# Efficient way to take the minimum/maximum n values and indices from a matrix using NumPy

Tags: python, optimization, performance, numpy

What's an efficient way, given a NumPy matrix (2D array), to return the minimum/maximum `n` values (along with their indices) in the array?

Currently I have:

```
def n_max(arr, n):
    res = [(0,(0,0))]*n
    for y in xrange(len(arr)):
        for x in xrange(len(arr[y])):
            val = float(arr[y,x])
            el = (val,(y,x))
            i = bisect.bisect(res, el)
            if i > 0:
                res.insert(i, el)
                del res[0]
    return res
```

This takes three times longer than the image template matching algorithm that `pyopencv` does to generate the array I want to run this on, and I figure that's silly.

Comment: What's a typical ratio of `n` to `len(arr)`?

Comment: @Paul: tiny.. i'm finding the number of matches of a template to an image, so it's # of matches to # of pixels in the image, like 20 to 150000

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since the time of the other answer, NumPy has added the [`numpy.partition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) and [`numpy.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) functions for partial sorting, allowing you to do this in `O(arr.size)` time, or `O(arr.size+n*log(n))` if you need the elements in sorted order.

`numpy.partition(arr, n)` returns an array the size of `arr` where the `n`th element is what it would be if the array were sorted. All smaller elements come before that element and all greater elements come afterward.

`numpy.argpartition` is to `numpy.partition` as `numpy.argsort` is to `numpy.sort`.

Here's how you would use these functions to find the indices of the minimum `n` elements of a two-dimensional `arr`:

```
flat_indices = numpy.argpartition(arr.ravel(), n-1)[:n]
row_indices, col_indices = numpy.unravel_index(flat_indices, arr.shape)
```

And if you need the indices in order, so `row_indices[0]` is the row of the minimum element instead of just one of the `n` minimum elements:

```
min_elements = arr[row_indices, col_indices]
min_elements_order = numpy.argsort(min_elements)
row_indices, col_indices = row_indices[min_elements_order], col_indices[min_elements_order]
```

---

The 1D case is a lot simpler:

```
# Unordered:
indices = numpy.argpartition(arr, n-1)[:n]

# Extra code if you need the indices in order:
min_elements = arr[indices]
min_elements_order = numpy.argsort(min_elements)
ordered_indices = indices[min_elements_order]
```

Comment: This exact code gave me ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @WayneFilkins: Sounds like you tried to use it on a 1D array instead of a 2D array. The 1D case is simpler, but you can't throw the 2D case code at a 1D array.

Comment: This is the fastest solution I've found so far.  However, argpartition requires O(arr.size) storage!  I'm surprised that nobody came up with a better solution requiring O(n) temporary storage instead.

Comment: @MichelLemay: `heapq.nlargest` and `heapq.nsmallest` exist, but have worse time complexity and don't take advantage of NumPy functionality.

Comment: yes, I've tried them and they are too slow.  In my case, the array is multidimensional and contains millions of columns. Allocating that takes a significant amount of time to just throw away 99.99% of it to the garbage collector.

Comment: @MichelLemay: You could try just writing a heap-based algorithm with Cython or Numba and see if that works out better for you.

Comment: Lol I think I cannot invent space or time..  Using a max-heap will yield O(N + k log N) time and O(N) storage..  Using a heapq will yield O(N * log K) time and O(k) storage which is way worse than max-heap if k is larger than a handful..

Answer (score 9):

Since there is no heap implementation in NumPy, probably your best guess is to sort the whole array and take the last `n` elements:

```
def n_max(arr, n):
    indices = arr.ravel().argsort()[-n:]
    indices = (numpy.unravel_index(i, arr.shape) for i in indices)
    return [(arr[i], i) for i in indices]
```

(This will probably return the list in reverse order compared to your implementation - I did not check.)

A more efficient solution that works with newer versions of NumPy is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38772601/279627).

Comment: if `n` is small then perhaps running `argmax` a few times (removing the max each time) could be faster.

Comment: nice, this is much much faster than mine. should be good enough

Comment: No expert with NumPy, but do we really need to sort (O(n log n)) for something which is trivially done in O(n)? I assume the advantage is that the sorting is done in C while the looping code is run by the python interpreter?

Comment: @Voo: The complexity of the OP's algorithm is `O(m log n)`, where `m` is the number of elements in the array and `n` is the number of highest elements to find.  The algorithm in my answer is `O(m log m)`.  The factor between these two complexities for `m` and `n` as in the OP's above comment is 4, which is more than compensated for by getting rid of the Python loops.  As Paul noted above, if `n` is really small, there might be better alternatives.

Comment: @Voo: yea complexity isn't everything. in this case having this done in C beats mine by a lot (~3x faster) - and by enough so that i no longer have to worry about it, though if i need something faster i'll come back for more. but - how would you trivially do it on O(n)?

Comment: You _don't_ trivially do it in `O(n)`. Not without reverse tachyon quantum computing, anyway. Finding the maximum value of an array of size `m` is trivially `O(m)`. Interestingly, finding the `n` largest values of that array is _also_ `O(m)` – though _definitely_ not trivially. Basically, you **(A)** perform an [unordered partial selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) of the array in `O(m)` for the `n` largest values and **(B)** retrieve these values from the partially sorted array in `O(n)` time. Since `n << m`, this remains `O(m)`.

Comment: NumPy has [`numpy.partition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) and [`numpy.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html), which would let you do this in O(arr.size), or O(arr.size+n*log(n)) if you need the n items in order.

Comment: @user2357112 Nice.  Care to add this as a separate answer?  (The function was introduced more than two years after I answered this question, so I guess at the time my answer was accurate.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Ah, I didn't realize. I don't know where to find NumPy release dates, so I wasn't sure whether 1.8.0 was released before or after this answer. Separate answer added.

Comment: @user2357112: Thanks!  Numpy release dates can be found here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases

Answer (score 0):

I just met the exact same problem and solved it.
Here is my solution, wrapping the np.argpartition:

- Applied to arbitrary axis.
- High speed when K << array.shape[axis], o(N).
- Return both the sorted result and the corresponding indexs in original matrix.

```
def get_sorted_smallest_K(array, K, axis=-1):
    # Find the least K values of array along the given axis. 
    # Only efficient when K << array.shape[axis].
    # Return:
    #   top_sorted_scores: np.array. The least K values.
    #   top_sorted_indexs: np.array. The least K indexs of original input array.
    
    partition_index = np.take(np.argpartition(array, K, axis), range(0, K), axis)
    top_scores = np.take_along_axis(array, partition_index, axis)
    sorted_index = np.argsort(top_scores, axis=axis)
    top_sorted_scores = np.take_along_axis(top_scores, sorted_index, axis)
    top_sorted_indexs = np.take_along_axis(partition_index, sorted_index, axis)
    return top_sorted_scores, top_sorted_indexs
```