# How do I get indices of N maximum values in a NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy, max, numpy-ndarray

NumPy proposes a way to get the index of the maximum value of an array via [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).

I would like a similar thing, but returning the indexes of the `N` maximum values.

For instance, if I have an array, `[1, 3, 2, 4, 5]`, then `nargmax(array, n=3)` would return the indices `[4, 3, 1]` which correspond to the elements `[5, 4, 3]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python+numpy: efficient way to take the min/max n values and indices from a matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807047/pythonnumpy-efficient-way-to-take-the-min-max-n-values-and-indices-from-a-matri)

Comment: Your question is not really well defined. For example, what would the indices (you expect) to be for `array([5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5])`, whit `n=  3`? Which one of all the alternatives, like `[0, 2, 3]`, `[0, 2, 9]`, `...` would be the correct one? Please elaborate more on your specific requirements. Thanks

Comment: @eat, I don't really care about which one is supposed to be returned in this specific case. Even if it seem logical to return the first one encountered, that's not a requirement for me.

Comment: `argsort` might be a viable alternative if you do not care about the order of the returned indeces. See my answer below.

Answer (score 997, accepted):

Newer NumPy versions (1.8 and up) have a function called [`argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) for this. To get the indices of the four largest elements, do

```
>>> a = np.array([9, 4, 4, 3, 3, 9, 0, 4, 6, 0])
>>> a
array([9, 4, 4, 3, 3, 9, 0, 4, 6, 0])

>>> ind = np.argpartition(a, -4)[-4:]
>>> ind
array([1, 5, 8, 0])

>>> top4 = a[ind]
>>> top4
array([4, 9, 6, 9])
```

Unlike [`argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), this function runs in linear time in the worst case, but the returned indices are not sorted, as can be seen from the result of evaluating `a[ind]`. If you need that too, sort them afterwards:

```
>>> ind[np.argsort(a[ind])]
array([1, 8, 5, 0])
```

To get the top-*k* elements in sorted order in this way takes O(*n* + *k* log *k*) time.

Comment: Actually it has to be O(n lg k) time. Cannot imagine how O(n + k lg k) can be

Comment: @varela `argpartition` runs in linear time, O(n), using the [introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect) algorithm. The subsequent sort only handles k elements, so that runs in O(k log k).

Comment: If anybody is wondering how exactly `np.argpartition` and its sister algorithm `np.partition` work there is a more detailed explanation in the linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337533/a-fast-way-to-find-the-largest-n-elements-in-an-numpy-array?lq=1

Comment: @FredFoo: why did you use -4? did you do that to start backward?(since k being positive or negative works the same for me! it only prints the smallest numbers first!

Comment: Running: `{import numpy as np
a = [9, 4, 4, 3, 3, 9, 0, 4, 6, 0]
ind = np.argpartition(a, -4)[-4:]
a[ind]}` now throws this error. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Comment: @LKT use `a=np.array([9, 4, 4, 3, 3, 9, 0, 4, 6, 0])` because normal python lists do not support indexing by lists, unlike `np.array`

Comment: how to use this method to find the indices of top n values of each row of a matrix?

Comment: @Umangsinghal ```np.argpartition``` takes an optional ```axis``` argument. To find the indices of the top n values for each row: ```np.argpartition(a, -n, axis=1)[-n:]```

Comment: @Umangsinghal For the top n values of each row, making sure the results are sorted at the end is more complicated. n should be a negative range, and you need to properly flip the order at the end as well:
np.argpartition(matrix, range(-n, 0), axis=1)[:, ::-1]
For some reason it's taken me many months to get to a good answer on this.

Comment: Be carefull with the sort trick though if you need a stable sort over the whole array: if the biggest k-th value is equal to other values in the initial array, then you have no guarantee that these values will appear in the same order in the final result because some of these "equal values" might be included in the output and some others not.

Comment: @JoshuaM And still incorrect. Correct way would be `np.argpartition(matrix, range(-n, 0), axis=1)[:, :-(n+1):-1]`

Comment: @jwalton Don't you mean `np.argpartition(a, -n, axis=1)[:, -n:]`?

Comment: If I want to get the smallest k and biggest k values of the array at the same time, is there any better way than simply applying this solution twice?

Comment: @Hossein `-4` vs `4` does indeed matter for `np.argpartition(a, -4)`. In this example it happens to give the same result, while `-2` and `2` give different results.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `kth` argument of `np.argpartition()` refers to the kth element of the _resulted_ array, not the primary array. That's why when we want the 4 largest elements, we give `-4` to `np.argpartition()` or `np.partition()`. It causes the _last 4 elements_ of the resulted array to be the 4 largest elements. More: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41484104/4526384

Comment: could it be O(n*k *log(k))? It seems to me that it cannot be smaller than O(n*k) that's the number of outputs

Answer (score 513):

The simplest I've been able to come up with is:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 5])
>>> arr.argsort()[-3:][::-1]
array([4, 3, 1])
```

This involves a complete sort of the array. I wonder if `numpy` provides a built-in way to do a partial sort; so far I haven't been able to find one.

If this solution turns out to be too slow (especially for small `n`), it may be worth looking at coding something up in [Cython](http://cython.org/).

Comment: Could line 3 be written equivalently as `arr.argsort()[-1:-4:-1]`?  I've tried it in interpreter and it comes up with the same result, but I'm wondering if it's not broken by some example.

Comment: @abroekhof Yes that should be equivalent for any list or array.  Alternatively, this could be done without the reversal by using `np.argsort(-arr)[:3]`, which I find more readable and to the point.

Comment: what does [::-1] mean? @NPE

Comment: @1a1a11a it means reverse an array (literally, takes a copy of an array from unconstrained min to unconstrained max in a reversed order)

Comment: @FizBack so the two `:` does not related to dimensions right? the whole expression is used for create a reversed array? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: ```arr.argsort()[::-1][:n]``` is better because it returns empty for ```n=0``` instead of the full array

Comment: @NPE numpy has the function `argpartition` which will isolate the top K elements from the rest without doing a full sort, and then the sorting can be done only on those K.

Comment: It would be better if this was written in a general way and not specific to his array, which makes it unintelligible.

Comment: @askewchan Index reversal is much faster than inversion, though

Comment: @1a1a11a ```arr.argsort()[-3:]
>>>array([1, 3, 4], dtype=int64)

arr.argsort()[-3:][::-1]
>>>array([4, 3, 1], dtype=int64)```

Answer (score 82):

Simpler yet:

```
idx = (-arr).argsort()[:n]
```

where *n* is the number of maximum values.

Comment: Can this be done for a 2d array? If not, do you perhaps know how?

Comment: @AndrewHundt : simply use (-arr).argsort(axis=-1)[:, :n]

Comment: similar would be `arr[arr.argsort()[-n:]]` instead of negating the array, just take a slice of the last n elements

Comment: `ind = np.argsort(-arr,axis=0)[:4]` worked for me to find out first 4 index coloum wise

Answer (score 52):

Use:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 5])
>>> heapq.nlargest(3, range(len(a)), a.take)
[4, 3, 1]
```

For regular Python lists:

```
>>> a = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5]
>>> heapq.nlargest(3, range(len(a)), a.__getitem__)
[4, 3, 1]
```

If you use Python 2, use `xrange` instead of `range`.

Source: *[heapq — Heap queue algorithm](http://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html)*

Comment: There's no need of a loop at all here: `heapq.nlargest(3, xrange(len(a)), a.take)`. For Python lists we can use `.__getitem__` instead of `.take`.

Comment: For n-dimensional arrays `A` in general: `heapq.nlargest(3, range(len(A.ravel())), A.ravel().take)`. (I hope this only operates on views, see also (`ravel vs flatten`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28930580/603003)).

Answer (score 44):

If you happen to be working with a multidimensional array then you'll need to flatten and unravel the indices:

```
def largest_indices(ary, n):
    """Returns the n largest indices from a numpy array."""
    flat = ary.flatten()
    indices = np.argpartition(flat, -n)[-n:]
    indices = indices[np.argsort(-flat[indices])]
    return np.unravel_index(indices, ary.shape)
```

For example:

```
>>> xs = np.sin(np.arange(9)).reshape((3, 3))
>>> xs
array([[ 0.        ,  0.84147098,  0.90929743],
       [ 0.14112001, -0.7568025 , -0.95892427],
       [-0.2794155 ,  0.6569866 ,  0.98935825]])
>>> largest_indices(xs, 3)
(array([2, 0, 0]), array([2, 2, 1]))
>>> xs[largest_indices(xs, 3)]
array([ 0.98935825,  0.90929743,  0.84147098])
```

Answer (score 19):

### Three Answers Compared For Coding Ease And Speed

Speed was important for my needs, so I tested three answers to this question.

Code from those three answers was modified as needed for my specific case.

I then compared the speed of each method.

Coding wise:

1. NPE's answer was the next most elegant and adequately fast for my needs.
2. Fred Foos answer required the most refactoring for my needs but was the fastest. I went with this answer, because even though it took more work, it was not too bad and had significant speed advantages.
3. off99555's answer was the most elegant, but it is the slowest.

#### Complete Code for Test and Comparisons

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random
import sys
from operator import itemgetter
from heapq import nlargest

''' Fake Data Setup '''
a1 = list(range(1000000))
random.shuffle(a1)
a1 = np.array(a1)

''' ################################################ '''
''' NPE's Answer Modified A Bit For My Case '''
t0 = time.time()
indices = np.flip(np.argsort(a1))[:5]
results = []
for index in indices:
    results.append((index, a1[index]))
t1 = time.time()
print("NPE's Answer:")
print(results)
print(t1 - t0)
print()

''' Fred Foos Answer Modified A Bit For My Case'''
t0 = time.time()
indices = np.argpartition(a1, -6)[-5:]
results = []
for index in indices:
    results.append((a1[index], index))
results.sort(reverse=True)
results = [(b, a) for a, b in results]
t1 = time.time()
print("Fred Foo's Answer:")
print(results)
print(t1 - t0)
print()

''' off99555's Answer - No Modification Needed For My Needs '''
t0 = time.time()
result = nlargest(5, enumerate(a1), itemgetter(1))
t1 = time.time()
print("off99555's Answer:")
print(result)
print(t1 - t0)
```

### Output with Speed Reports

NPE's Answer:

```
[(631934, 999999), (788104, 999998), (413003, 999997), (536514, 999996), (81029, 999995)]
0.1349949836730957
```

Fred Foo's Answer:

```
[(631934, 999999), (788104, 999998), (413003, 999997), (536514, 999996), (81029, 999995)]
0.011161565780639648
```

off99555's Answer:

```
[(631934, 999999), (788104, 999998), (413003, 999997), (536514, 999996), (81029, 999995)]
0.439760684967041
```

Answer (score 15):

If you don't care about the *order* of the K-th largest elements you can use [`argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html), which should perform better than a full sort through `argsort`.

```
K = 4 # We want the indices of the four largest values
a = np.array([0, 8, 0, 4, 5, 8, 8, 0, 4, 2])
np.argpartition(a,-K)[-K:]
array([4, 1, 5, 6])
```

Credits go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226400/find-the-k-smallest-values-of-a-numpy-array).

I ran a few tests and it looks like `argpartition` outperforms `argsort` as the size of the array and the value of K increase.

Comment: If you do care about the order, just `argpartition` then `sort` :)

Answer (score 11):

For multidimensional arrays you can use the `axis` keyword in order to apply the partitioning along the expected axis.

```
# For a 2D array
indices = np.argpartition(arr, -N, axis=1)[:, -N:]
```

And for grabbing the items:

```
x = arr.shape[0]
arr[np.repeat(np.arange(x), N), indices.ravel()].reshape(x, N)
```

But note that this won't return a sorted result. In that case you can use `np.argsort()` along the intended axis:

```
indices = np.argsort(arr, axis=1)[:, -N:]

# Result
x = arr.shape[0]
arr[np.repeat(np.arange(x), N), indices.ravel()].reshape(x, N)
```

Here is an example:

```
In [42]: a = np.random.randint(0, 20, (10, 10))

In [44]: a
Out[44]:
array([[ 7, 11, 12,  0,  2,  3,  4, 10,  6, 10],
       [16, 16,  4,  3, 18,  5, 10,  4, 14,  9],
       [ 2,  9, 15, 12, 18,  3, 13, 11,  5, 10],
       [14,  0,  9, 11,  1,  4,  9, 19, 18, 12],
       [ 0, 10,  5, 15,  9, 18,  5,  2, 16, 19],
       [14, 19,  3, 11, 13, 11, 13, 11,  1, 14],
       [ 7, 15, 18,  6,  5, 13,  1,  7,  9, 19],
       [11, 17, 11, 16, 14,  3, 16,  1, 12, 19],
       [ 2,  4, 14,  8,  6,  9, 14,  9,  1,  5],
       [ 1, 10, 15,  0,  1,  9, 18,  2,  2, 12]])

In [45]: np.argpartition(a, np.argmin(a, axis=0))[:, 1:] # 1 is because the first item is the minimum one.
Out[45]:
array([[4, 5, 6, 8, 0, 7, 9, 1, 2],
       [2, 7, 5, 9, 6, 8, 1, 0, 4],
       [5, 8, 1, 9, 7, 3, 6, 2, 4],
       [4, 5, 2, 6, 3, 9, 0, 8, 7],
       [7, 2, 6, 4, 1, 3, 8, 5, 9],
       [2, 3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 0, 9, 1],
       [4, 3, 0, 7, 8, 5, 1, 2, 9],
       [5, 2, 0, 8, 4, 6, 3, 1, 9],
       [0, 1, 9, 4, 3, 7, 5, 2, 6],
       [0, 4, 7, 8, 5, 1, 9, 2, 6]])

In [46]: np.argpartition(a, np.argmin(a, axis=0))[:, -3:]
Out[46]:
array([[9, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 4],
       [6, 2, 4],
       [0, 8, 7],
       [8, 5, 9],
       [0, 9, 1],
       [1, 2, 9],
       [3, 1, 9],
       [5, 2, 6],
       [9, 2, 6]])

In [89]: a[np.repeat(np.arange(x), 3), ind.ravel()].reshape(x, 3)
Out[89]:
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [16, 16, 18],
       [13, 15, 18],
       [14, 18, 19],
       [16, 18, 19],
       [14, 14, 19],
       [15, 18, 19],
       [16, 17, 19],
       [ 9, 14, 14],
       [12, 15, 18]])
```

Comment: I think you can simplify the indexing here by using `np.take_along_axis` (which likely did not exist when you answered this question)

Comment: The default axis parameter for np.argpartition is -1 so no need set it to 1 in your 2D array case.

Answer (score 8):

Method `np.argpartition` only returns the k largest indices, performs a local sort, and is faster than `np.argsort`(performing a full sort) when array is quite large. But the returned indices are **NOT in ascending/descending order**. Let's say with an example:

[image]

We can see that if you want a strict ascending order top k indices, `np.argpartition` won't return what you want.

Apart from doing a sort manually after np.argpartition, my solution is to use PyTorch, [`torch.topk`](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.2.0/torch.html?highlight=topk#torch.topk), a tool for neural network construction, providing NumPy-like APIs with both CPU and GPU support. It's as fast as NumPy with MKL, and offers a GPU boost if you need large matrix/vector calculations.

Strict ascend/descend top k indices code will be:

[image]

Note that [`torch.topk`](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.2.0/torch.html?highlight=topk#torch.topk) accepts a torch tensor, and returns both top k values and top k indices in type `torch.Tensor`. Similar with np, torch.topk also accepts an axis argument so that you can handle multi-dimensional arrays/tensors.

Comment: Code snippets are replicate when you share screenshots. Code blocks will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This will be faster than a full sort depending on the size of your original array and the size of your selection:

```
>>> A = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
>>> A
array([5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 0])
>>> B = np.zeros(3, int)
>>> for i in xrange(3):
...     idx = np.argmax(A)
...     B[i]=idx; A[idx]=0 #something smaller than A.min()
...     
>>> B
array([0, 2, 3])
```

It, of course, involves tampering with your original array.  Which you could fix (if needed) by making a copy or replacing back the original values.  ...whichever is cheaper for your use case.

Comment: FWIW, your solution won't provide unambiguous solution in all situations. OP should describe how to handle these unambiguous cases. Thanks

Comment: @eat  The OP's question is a little ambiguous.  An implementation, however, is not really open to interpretation. :)  The OP should simply refer to the definition of np.argmax http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html to be sure this specific solution meets the requirements.  It's possible that any solution meeting the OP's stated reqirement is acceptable..

Comment: Well, one might consider the implementation of `argmax(.)` to be unambiguous as well. (IMHO it tries to follow some kind of short circuiting logic, but unfortunately fails to provide universally acceptable behavior). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from heapq import nlargest
result = nlargest(N, enumerate(your_list), itemgetter(1))
```

Now the `result` list would contain **N** tuples (`index`, `value`) where `value` is maximized.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
def max_indices(arr, k):
    '''
    Returns the indices of the k first largest elements of arr
    (in descending order in values)
    '''
    assert k <= arr.size, 'k should be smaller or equal to the array size'
    arr_ = arr.astype(float)  # make a copy of arr
    max_idxs = []
    for _ in range(k):
        max_element = np.max(arr_)
        if np.isinf(max_element):
            break
        else:
            idx = np.where(arr_ == max_element)
        max_idxs.append(idx)
        arr_[idx] = -np.inf
    return max_idxs
```

It also works with 2D arrays. For example,

```
In [0]: A = np.array([[ 0.51845014,  0.72528114],
                     [ 0.88421561,  0.18798661],
                     [ 0.89832036,  0.19448609],
                     [ 0.89832036,  0.19448609]])
In [1]: max_indices(A, 8)
Out[1]:
    [(array([2, 3], dtype=int64), array([0, 0], dtype=int64)),
     (array([1], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64)),
     (array([0], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64)),
     (array([0], dtype=int64), array([0], dtype=int64)),
     (array([2, 3], dtype=int64), array([1, 1], dtype=int64)),
     (array([1], dtype=int64), array([1], dtype=int64))]

In [2]: A[max_indices(A, 8)[0]][0]
Out[2]: array([ 0.89832036])
```

Comment: Works good, but gives more results if you have duplicate (maximum) values in your array A. I would expect exactly k results but in case of duplicate values, you get more than k results.

Comment: I slightly modified the code. The list of indices that is returned has length equal exactly to k. If you have duplicates, they are grouped into a single tuple.

Answer (score 2):

A vectorized 2D implementation using **argpartition**:

```
k = 3
probas = np.array([
    [.6, .1, .15, .15],
    [.1, .6, .15, .15],
    [.3, .1, .6, 0],
])

k_indices = np.argpartition(-probas, k-1, axis=-1)[:, :k]

# adjust indices to apply in flat array
adjuster = np.arange(probas.shape[0]) * probas.shape[1]
adjuster = np.broadcast_to(adjuster[:, None], k_indices.shape)
k_indices_flat = k_indices + adjuster

k_values = probas.flatten()[k_indices_flat]

# k_indices:
# array([[0, 2, 3],
#        [1, 2, 3],
#        [2, 0, 1]])
# k_values:
# array([[0.6 , 0.15, 0.15],
#        [0.6 , 0.15, 0.15],
#       [0.6 , 0.3 , 0.1 ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it most intuitive to use `np.unique`.

The idea is, that the unique method returns the indices of the input values. Then from the max unique value and the indicies, the position of the original values can be recreated.

```
multi_max = [1,1,2,2,4,0,0,4]
uniques, idx = np.unique(multi_max, return_inverse=True)
print np.squeeze(np.argwhere(idx == np.argmax(uniques)))
>> [4 7]
```

Comment: I used this answer to get the top n distinct values, using the sorted `idx` to index `uniques`: `top5distinct = uniques[np.argsort(idx)[::-1][:5]]`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a very easy way to see the maximum elements and its positions. Here `axis` is the domain; `axis` = 0 means column wise maximum number and `axis` = 1 means row wise max number for the 2D case. And for higher dimensions it depends upon you.

```
M = np.random.random((3, 4))
print(M)
print(M.max(axis=1), M.argmax(axis=1))
```

Comment: I used this link https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.04-computation-on-arrays-aggregates.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more complicated way that increases n if the nth value has ties:

```
>>>> def get_top_n_plus_ties(arr,n):
>>>>     sorted_args = np.argsort(-arr)
>>>>     thresh = arr[sorted_args[n]]
>>>>     n_ = np.sum(arr >= thresh)
>>>>     return sorted_args[:n_]
>>>> get_top_n_plus_ties(np.array([2,9,8,3,0,2,8,3,1,9,5]),3)
array([1, 9, 2, 6])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most time efficiency way is manually iterate through the array and keep a k-size min-heap, as other people have mentioned.

And I also come up with a brute force approach:

```
top_k_index_list = [ ]
for i in range(k):
    top_k_index_list.append(np.argmax(my_array))
    my_array[top_k_index_list[-1]] = -float('inf')
```

Set the largest element to a large negative value after you use argmax to get its index. And then the next call of argmax will return the second largest element.
And you can log the original value of these elements and recover them if you want.

Comment: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 0):

This code works for a numpy ***2D matrix*** array:

```
mat = np.array([[1, 3], [2, 5]]) # numpy matrix
 
n = 2  # n
n_largest_mat = np.sort(mat, axis=None)[-n:] # n_largest 
tf_n_largest = np.zeros((2,2), dtype=bool) # all false matrix
for x in n_largest_mat: 
  tf_n_largest = (tf_n_largest) | (mat == x) # true-false  

n_largest_elems = mat[tf_n_largest] # true-false indexing
```

This produces a true-false n_largest matrix indexing that also works to extract n_largest elements from a matrix array

Answer (score 0):

When top_k<<axis_length,it better than argsort.

```
import numpy as np

def get_sorted_top_k(array, top_k=1, axis=-1, reverse=False):
    if reverse:
        axis_length = array.shape[axis]
        partition_index = np.take(np.argpartition(array, kth=-top_k, axis=axis),
                                  range(axis_length - top_k, axis_length), axis)
    else:
        partition_index = np.take(np.argpartition(array, kth=top_k, axis=axis), range(0, top_k), axis)
    top_scores = np.take_along_axis(array, partition_index, axis)
    # resort partition
    sorted_index = np.argsort(top_scores, axis=axis)
    if reverse:
        sorted_index = np.flip(sorted_index, axis=axis)
    top_sorted_scores = np.take_along_axis(top_scores, sorted_index, axis)
    top_sorted_indexes = np.take_along_axis(partition_index, sorted_index, axis)
    return top_sorted_scores, top_sorted_indexes

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

    x = np.random.rand(10, 128)
    y = np.random.rand(1000000, 128)
    z = cosine_similarity(x, y)
    start_time = time.time()
    sorted_index_1 = get_sorted_top_k(z, top_k=3, axis=1, reverse=True)[1]
    print(time.time() - start_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a dictionary to find top k values & indices in a numpy array.
For example, if you want to find top 2 maximum values & indices

```
import numpy as np
nums = np.array([0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.15, 0.1])


def TopK(x, k):
    a = dict([(i, j) for i, j in enumerate(x)])
    sorted_a = dict(sorted(a.items(), key = lambda kv:kv[1], reverse=True))
    indices = list(sorted_a.keys())[:k]
    values = list(sorted_a.values())[:k]
    return (indices, values)

print(f"Indices: {TopK(nums, k = 2)[0]}")
print(f"Values: {TopK(nums, k = 2)[1]}")


Indices: [1, 2]
Values: [0.3, 0.25]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with NaNs and/or have problems understanding np.argpartition, try [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    

a = np.array([9, 4, 4, 3, 3, 9, 0, 4, 6, 0])

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['array'])
max_values = df['array'].sort_values(ascending=False, na_position='last')
ind = max_values[0:3].index.to_list()
```

This example gives the indices of the 3 largest, not-NaN values. Probably inefficient, but easy to read and customize.