# A fast way to find the largest N elements in an numpy array

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I know I  can do it like the following:

```
import numpy as np
N=10
a=np.arange(1,100,1)
np.argsort()[-N:]
```

However, it is very slow since it did a full sort.

I wonder whether numpy provide some methods the do it fast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get indices of N maximum values in a numpy array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-to-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The [`bottleneck`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Bottleneck) module has a fast partial sort method that works directly with Numpy arrays: [`bottleneck.partition()`](http://berkeleyanalytics.com/bottleneck/reference.html#bottleneck.partition).

Note that `bottleneck.partition()` returns the actual values sorted, if you want the indexes of the sorted values (what `numpy.argsort()` returns) you should use [`bottleneck.argpartition()`](http://berkeleyanalytics.com/bottleneck/reference.html#bottleneck.argpartition).

I've benchmarked:

- `z = -bottleneck.partition(-a, 10)[:10]`
- `z = a.argsort()[-10:]`
- `z = heapq.nlargest(10, a)`

where `a` is a random 1,000,000-element array.

The timings were as follows:

- `bottleneck.partition()`: 25.6 ms per loop
- `np.argsort()`: 198 ms per loop
- `heapq.nlargest()`: 358 ms per loop

Comment: @Mike Graham: Thanks for the edit, but `nanargmax()` does something rather different to what the OP is asking. I'm going to roll back the edit. Correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Probably bottleneck is faster, but since it is not provided in EPD7.1, we may not use that.

Comment: @HailiangZhang: I too would love to see `bottleneck` added to EPD.

Comment: For the record, `bottleneck.partsort()` and `np.argsort()` are doing two slightly different things. They return a value and an index respectively. If you want bottleneck to return the index, use `bottleneck.argpartsort`

Comment: The timing on `heapq.nlargest` isn't quite fair.  It would be better to run `heapq.nlargest(10, a.tolist())`

Answer (score 89):

`numpy 1.8` implements `partition` and `argpartition` that perform partial sort ( in O(n) time as opposed to full sort that is O(n) * log(n)).

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([9,1,3,4,8,7,2,5,6,0])

temp = np.argpartition(-test, 4)
result_args = temp[:4]

temp = np.partition(-test, 4)
result = -temp[:4]
```

Result:

```
>>> result_args
array([0, 4, 8, 5]) # indices of highest vals
>>> result
array([9, 8, 6, 7]) # highest vals
```

Timing:

```
In [16]: a = np.arange(10000)

In [17]: np.random.shuffle(a)

In [18]: %timeit np.argsort(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop

In [19]: %timeit np.argpartition(a, 100)
10000 loops, best of 3: 139 us per loop

In [20]: %timeit np.argpartition(a, 1000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 141 us per loop
```

Comment: Note that may be helpful to others: The example is not the best choice, since the result is not guaranteed to be in order

Comment: @user3080953. I never say the result is guaranteed to be in order, that's what partial sort is. And in the example I provide: `[9, 8, 6, 7]` it is clear that n highest vals are not in order.

Comment: yup, in hindsight, it's obvious because you can't sort in O(n). I spent 20 minutes looking for a bug, and thought this might be helpful for other people reading this

Comment: @user3080953. Try set "kth" as a sequence, as noted in the doc of numpy.argpartition -- "If provided with a sequence of k-th it will partition all of them into their sorted position at once."  And, the example following the doc -- >>> x = np.array([3, 4, 2, 1])
>>> x[np.argpartition(x, 3)]
array([2, 1, 3, 4])
>>> x[np.argpartition(x, (1, 3))]
array([1, 2, 3, 4])  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html

Comment: Can we also get an explanation why the array is inverted during the `argpartition`? Shouldn't it be inherently the same, but with the selection on `temp[:5]` instead of `temp[4:]` then? Or am I missing a crucial detail here?

Comment: @dennlinger By 'inverted', are you referring to `-test`? `np.partition` sort in increasing order by default. In order to sort in descending order, we can turn all the numbers into negative (`array([-9, -1, -3, -4, -8, -7, -2, -5, -6,  0])`) and sort in that array instead.

Answer (score 19):

I had this problem and, since this question is 5 years old, I had to redo all benchmarks and change the syntax of bottleneck (there is no `partsort` anymore, it's `partition` now).

I used the same arguments as kwgoodman, except the number of elements retrieved, which I increased to 50 (to better fit my particular situation).

I got these results:

```
bottleneck 1: 01.12 ms per loop
bottleneck 2: 00.95 ms per loop
pandas      : 01.65 ms per loop
heapq       : 08.61 ms per loop
numpy       : 12.37 ms per loop
numpy 2     : 00.95 ms per loop
```

So, bottleneck_2 and numpy_2 (adas's solution) were tied.
But, using `np.percentile` (numpy_2) you have those topN elements already sorted, which is not the case for the other solutions. On the other hand, if you are also interested on the indexes of those elements, percentile is not useful.

I added pandas too, which uses bottleneck underneath, if available (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#recommended-dependencies). If you already have a pandas Series or DataFrame to start with, you are in good hands, just use `nlargest` and you're done.

The code used for the benchmark is as follows (python 3, please):

```
import time
import numpy as np
import bottleneck as bn
import pandas as pd
import heapq

def bottleneck_1(a, n):
    return -bn.partition(-a, n)[:n]

def bottleneck_2(a, n):
    return bn.partition(a, a.size-n)[-n:]

def numpy(a, n):
    return a[a.argsort()[-n:]]

def numpy_2(a, n):
    M = a.shape[0]
    perc = (np.arange(M-n,M)+1.0)/M*100
    return np.percentile(a,perc)

def pandas(a, n):
    return pd.Series(a).nlargest(n)

def hpq(a, n):
    return heapq.nlargest(n, a)

def do_nothing(a, n):
    return a[:n]

def benchmark(func, size=1000000, ntimes=100, topn=50):
    t1 = time.time()
    for n in range(ntimes):
        a = np.random.rand(size)
        func(a, topn)
    t2 = time.time()
    ms_per_loop = 1000000 * (t2 - t1) / size
    return ms_per_loop

t1 = benchmark(bottleneck_1)
t2 = benchmark(bottleneck_2)
t3 = benchmark(pandas)
t4 = benchmark(hpq)
t5 = benchmark(numpy)
t6 = benchmark(numpy_2)
t0 = benchmark(do_nothing)

print("bottleneck 1: {:05.2f} ms per loop".format(t1 - t0))
print("bottleneck 2: {:05.2f} ms per loop".format(t2 - t0))
print("pandas      : {:05.2f} ms per loop".format(t3 - t0))
print("heapq       : {:05.2f} ms per loop".format(t4 - t0))
print("numpy       : {:05.2f} ms per loop".format(t5 - t0))
print("numpy 2     : {:05.2f} ms per loop".format(t6 - t0))
```

Comment: thanks for the code! I also tested np.argpartition and found that it's 10x slower than np.argmax, when argpartition is set to find the top 1 element.

Comment: Can you add `np.argpartition`?

Answer (score 11):

Each negative sign in the proposed bottleneck solution

```
-bottleneck.partsort(-a, 10)[:10]
```

makes a copy of the data. We can remove the copies by doing

```
bottleneck.partsort(a, a.size-10)[-10:]
```

Also the proposed numpy solution

```
a.argsort()[-10:]
```

returns indices not values. The fix is to use the indices to find the values:

```
a[a.argsort()[-10:]]
```

The relative speed of the two bottleneck solutions depends on the ordering of the elements in the initial array because the two approaches partition the data at different points.

In other words, timing with any one particular random array can make either method look faster.

Averaging the timing across 100 random arrays, each with 1,000,000 elements, gives

```
-bn.partsort(-a, 10)[:10]: 1.76 ms per loop
bn.partsort(a, a.size-10)[-10:]: 0.92 ms per loop
a[a.argsort()[-10:]]: 15.34 ms per loop
```

where the timing code is as follows:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import bottleneck as bn

def bottleneck_1(a):
    return -bn.partsort(-a, 10)[:10]

def bottleneck_2(a):
    return bn.partsort(a, a.size-10)[-10:]

def numpy(a):
    return a[a.argsort()[-10:]]

def do_nothing(a):
    return a

def benchmark(func, size=1000000, ntimes=100):
    t1 = time.time()
    for n in range(ntimes):
        a = np.random.rand(size)
        func(a)
    t2 = time.time()
    ms_per_loop = 1000000 * (t2 - t1) / size
    return ms_per_loop

t1 = benchmark(bottleneck_1)
t2 = benchmark(bottleneck_2)
t3 = benchmark(numpy)
t4 = benchmark(do_nothing)

print "-bn.partsort(-a, 10)[:10]: %0.2f ms per loop" % (t1 - t4)
print "bn.partsort(a, a.size-10)[-10:]: %0.2f ms per loop" % (t2 - t4)
print "a[a.argsort()[-10:]]: %0.2f ms per loop" % (t3 - t4)
```

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps `heapq.nlargest`

```
import numpy as np
import heapq

x = np.array([1,-5,4,6,-3,3])

z = heapq.nlargest(3,x)
```

Result:

```
>>> z
[6, 4, 3]
```

If you want to find the indices of the `n` largest elements using `bottleneck` you could use
`bottleneck.argpartsort`

```
>>> x = np.array([1,-5,4,6,-3,3])
>>> z = bottleneck.argpartsort(-x, 3)[:3]
>>> z
array([3, 2, 5]
```

Comment: But heap q is actually slower (also mentioned by the next reply).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use numpy's percentile function. In my case it was slightly faster then bottleneck.partsort():

```
import timeit
import bottleneck as bn

N,M,K = 10,1000000,100

start = timeit.default_timer()
for k in range(K):
    a=np.random.uniform(size=M)
    tmp=-bn.partsort(-a, N)[:N]
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print (stop - start)/K

start = timeit.default_timer()
perc = (np.arange(M-N,M)+1.0)/M*100
for k in range(K):
    a=np.random.uniform(size=M)
    tmp=np.percentile(a,perc)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print (stop - start)/K
```

Average time per loop:

- bottleneck.partsort(): 59 ms
- np.percentile(): 54 ms

Comment: Note that percentile might interpolate some values by default. If you want _exactly_ the same values as in the input array you can add the argument `interpolation='nearest'` to the call to `np.percentile`. See [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If storing the array as a list of numbers isn't problematic, you can use

```
import heapq
heapq.nlargest(N, a)
```

to get the `N` largest members.