# NumPy: finding N largest elements in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Edited since my last question was a duplicate, but I'm struggling with this as well. I'm currently working with a matrix and can easily find the largest element with

```
M[M != 1].max()
```

However, I'm interested in getting the N largest elements and can't find an easy way to do this with matrices. Is there an efficient solution?

Comment: Hi @planner15 - as per the link, `np.where(M == M[M != 0].min())` should return the row and column indices corresponding to the minimum element.

Comment: The revised question is still a duplicate, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10337533/2379410), and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6910641/2379410) for finding the indices.

Comment: @moarningsun I saw those, but those are for arrays. Would they still apply to matrices?

Comment: @planner15: The same basic idea applies, but you may need to do some small syntactical changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a `where` method which takes a condition as one of the parameter ,

```
minimum = M[M != 0].min()

print numpy.where(M==minimum)
```