# Find names of n largest values in each row of dataframe

Tags: pandas

I can find the n largest values in each row of a numpy array ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332908/n-largest-values-in-each-row-of-ndarray)) but doing so loses the column information which is what I want. Say I have some data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.rand(5,5)
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = list('abcde'))
data

          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.374540  0.950714  0.731994  0.598658  0.156019
1  0.155995  0.058084  0.866176  0.601115  0.708073
2  0.020584  0.969910  0.832443  0.212339  0.181825
3  0.183405  0.304242  0.524756  0.431945  0.291229
4  0.611853  0.139494  0.292145  0.366362  0.456070
```

I want the names of the largest contributors in each row. So for `n = 2` the output would be:

```
0  b  c
1  c  e
2  b  c
3  c  d
4  a  e
```

I can do it by looping over the dataframe but that would be inefficient. Is there a more pythonic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`pandas.Series.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) function:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).index.values, axis=1)
```

---

```
0    [b, c]
1    [c, e]
2    [b, c]
3    [c, d]
4    [a, e]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using [`numpy.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) to find the top n index per row and then extract column names by index:

```
import numpy as np
nlargest_index = np.argpartition(data.values, data.shape[1] - n)[:, -n:]
data.columns.values[nlargest_index]

#array([['c', 'b'],
#       ['e', 'c'],
#       ['c', 'b'],
#       ['d', 'c'],
#       ['e', 'a']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Your solution has the advantage that it gives the indices as well. How can I use this array of indices to extract the corresponding value from the original dataframe?

Comment: You can use [advanced indexing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_advanced_indexing.htm): `data.values[np.arange(len(data))[:,None], nlargest_index]`

Comment: The code works but transferring it to the original data it seems that it only works if there are no nan's in the data.

Comment: Order is not assured with argpartition, the nlargest solution is relatively slower but ensures order

Answer (score 1):

Can a dense ranking be used for this?

```
N = 2
threshold = len(data.columns) - N
nlargest = data[data.rank(method="dense", axis=1) > threshold]
```

```
>>> nlargest
          a         b         c         d         e
0       NaN  0.950714  0.731994       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       NaN  0.866176       NaN  0.708073
2       NaN  0.969910  0.832443       NaN       NaN
3       NaN       NaN  0.524756  0.431945       NaN
4  0.611853       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.456070
```

```
>>> nlargest.stack()
0  b    0.950714
   c    0.731994
1  c    0.866176
   e    0.708073
2  b    0.969910
   c    0.832443
3  c    0.524756
   d    0.431945
4  a    0.611853
   e    0.456070
dtype: float64
```