# Find indices of x minimum values of a list

Tags: python, list, min

I have a list of length n.

I want to find the indices that hold the 5 minimum values of this list.

I know how to find the index holding the minimum value using `operator`

```
min_index,min_value = min(enumerate(list), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Can this code be altered to get a list of the 5 indices I am after?

Comment: `sorted(...)[:5]` is the most direct way, not sure there is an optimized version.   [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-to-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array) about numpy arrays

Comment: This gives the min values, not the indices holding the values.

Comment: `sorted(enumerate(list), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[:5]` it uses the same call signature as `min`.

Comment: If can use `numpy.argpartition`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337533/a-fast-way-to-find-the-largest-n-elements-in-an-numpy-array/20177786#20177786.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this requires sorting the entire list, you can get a slice of the `sorted` list:

```
data = sorted(enumerate(list), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[:5]
```

Answer (score 2):

if use package `heapq`, it can be done by `nsamllest`:

```
heapq.nsmallest(5, enumerate(list), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

what about something like this?

```
    map(lambda x: [a.index(x),x],sorted(list)[:5])
```

that will return a list of lists where list[x][0] = the index and list[x][1] = the value

EDIT:

This assumes the list doesn't have repeated minimum values. As adhg McDonald-Jensen pointed out, it this will only return the first instance of the give value.

Comment: oh my goodness no, `[1,1,1,1,1,5,6,7,8]` should return `[0,1,2,3,4]` but using index will instead give `[0,0,0,0,0]`