# Getting n-th ranked column IDs per row of a dataframe - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, ranking

I am trying to find a method for finding the nth ranked value and returning the column name. So for example, given a data-frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns = list('ABCD'))

# Return column name of "MAX" value, compared to other columns in any particular row.

df['MAX1_NAMES'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)

print df

          A         B         C         D MAX1_NAMES
0 -0.728424 -0.764682 -1.506795  0.722246          D
1  1.305500 -1.191558  0.068829 -1.244659          A
2 -0.175834 -0.140273  1.117114  0.817358          C
3 -0.255825 -1.534035 -0.591206 -0.352594          A
4 -2.408806 -1.925055 -1.797020  2.381936          D
```

This would find the highest value in the rows and return the column name where it occurred. But I need the case where I can choose the particular rank of the desired value, and hopefully get a data frame like the following:

```
          A         B         C         D MAX1_NAMES  MAX2_NAMES
0 -0.728424 -0.764682 -1.506795  0.722246          D           A
1  1.305500 -1.191558  0.068829 -1.244659          A           C
2 -0.175834 -0.140273  1.117114  0.817358          C           D
3 -0.255825 -1.534035 -0.591206 -0.352594          A           D
4 -2.408806 -1.925055 -1.797020  2.381936          D           C
```

Where `MAX2_NAMES` is the second largest value in the row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking to perform the ranking for a particular rank `n` only, so I would like to suggest [`np.argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) that would get sorted indices just for the highest n-ranked entries at each row rather than sorting all elements. This is aimed at improved performance. The performance benefits are discussed in length in answers to [`A fast way to find the largest N elements in an numpy array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337533/a-fast-way-to-find-the-largest-n-elements-in-an-numpy-array) and hopefully we will reap the benefits here too.

Thus, in a function format, we would have -

```
def rank_df(df,rank):
    coln = 'MAX' + str(rank) + '_NAMES' 
    sortID = np.argpartition(-df[['A','B','C','D']].values,rank,axis=1)[:,rank-1]
    df[coln] = df.columns[sortID]
```

Sample run -

```
In [84]: df
Out[84]: 
          A         B         C         D
0 -0.124851  0.152432  1.436602 -0.391178
1  0.371932  1.732399  0.340876 -1.340609
2 -1.218608  0.444246  0.169968 -1.437259
3 -0.828132  0.821613 -0.556643 -0.407703
4 -0.390477  0.048824 -2.087323  1.597030

In [85]: rank_df(df,1)

In [86]: rank_df(df,2)

In [87]: df
Out[87]: 
          A         B         C         D MAX1_NAMES MAX2_NAMES
0 -0.124851  0.152432  1.436602 -0.391178          C          B
1  0.371932  1.732399  0.340876 -1.340609          B          A
2 -1.218608  0.444246  0.169968 -1.437259          B          C
3 -0.828132  0.821613 -0.556643 -0.407703          B          D
4 -0.390477  0.048824 -2.087323  1.597030          D          B
```

**Runtime test**

I am timing `np.argpartition` based approach as listed earlier in this post and `np.argsort` based one as listed in the other solution by @Psidom on a decent sized dataframe.

```
In [92]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 4), columns = list('ABCD'))

In [93]: %timeit rank_df(df,2)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop

In [94]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 4), columns = list('ABCD'))

In [95]: %timeit df['MAX2_NAMES'] = df.iloc[:,:4].apply(lambda r: r.index[r.argsort()[::-1][1]], axis = 1)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.32 s per loop
```

Comment: Very nice, I was more besotted with getting any solution regardless of speed, but the numpy sorting performance tip will come in handy.

Answer (score 4):

You can apply an `argsort()` per row, reverse the index and pick up the one at the second position:

```
df['MAX2_NAMES'] = df.iloc[:,:4].apply(lambda r: r.index[r.argsort()[::-1][1]], axis = 1)

df
#           A           B           C          D    MAX1_NAMES  MAX2_NAMES
#0  -0.728424   -0.764682   -1.506795   0.722246             D           A
#1  1.305500    -1.191558   0.068829    -1.244659            A           C
#2  -0.175834   -0.140273   1.117114    0.817358             C           D
#3  -0.255825   -1.534035   -0.591206   -0.352594            A           D
#4  -2.408806   -1.925055   -1.797020   2.381936             D           C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by combining rank, apply, and idxmin.

for example:

```
df = pd.util.testing.makeTimeDataFrame(5)

df
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-03 -1.814888 -0.709120 -0.134390 -0.906183
2000-01-04  0.459742  1.235481  0.109602 -0.226923
2000-01-05 -1.567867  0.562368 -1.185567 -2.176161
2000-01-06  0.747989 -0.160384  1.617100  0.242830
2000-01-07 -1.288061 -1.631342 -0.857830 -0.210695

df['rank_2_col'] = df.rank(1).apply(lambda r: r[r==2].idxmin(), axis=1)
df
                   A         B         C         D rank_2_col
2000-01-03 -1.814888 -0.709120 -0.134390 -0.906183      D
2000-01-04  0.459742  1.235481  0.109602 -0.226923      C
2000-01-05 -1.567867  0.562368 -1.185567 -2.176161      A
2000-01-06  0.747989 -0.160384  1.617100  0.242830      D
2000-01-07 -1.288061 -1.631342 -0.857830 -0.210695      A
```