# Numpy's partition slower than sort for small arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, sorting, numpy

I was looking for an efficient way to calculate the nth largest value in a numpy array and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337533/a-fast-way-to-find-the-largest-n-elements-in-an-numpy-array) lead me to [np.partition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html).

By the way, I have noticed that the naive sorting is faster than np.partition approach for array shorter than 100 entries.
(For large arrays, instead, the gain is evident)

What is the reason why np.partition run time is almost flat for small arrays?

[image]

Code to generate picture:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import timeit

def func_1(inp):
    return np.partition(inp, 10)[10]

def func_2(inp):
    return np.sort(inp)[10]

a = []
b = []

N_tests = int(1e5)

for wdw in range(20, 1000, 10):

    print wdw

    res1 = timeit.timeit("func_1(test)",
                      setup = "import pandas as pd; import numpy as np; wdw_size = %d; test = np.random.randn(wdw_size); from __main__ import func_1"%wdw, number = N_tests)

    a.append(res1)

    res2 = timeit.timeit("func_2(test)",
                      setup = "import pandas as pd; import numpy as np; wdw_size = %d; test = np.random.randn(wdw_size); from __main__ import func_2"%wdw, number = N_tests)

    b.append(res2)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(20,1000, 10), a, range(20, 1000, 10), b)
plt.legend(['np.partition', 'np.sort'])
plt.xlabel('Array Size')
plt.ylabel('Time')
```

Comment: For reliable benchmarks, maybe use a bigger number of iterations for the smaller datasets?

Comment: Fair suggestion. I have increased the number of iterations to 1e5, but still obtaining same qualitative result.

Comment: The answer is probably simply "because there is more overhead in setting up partition", even if in principle there shouldn't be. Perhaps look at the source code?

Comment: How does timing compare if you sort in place?

Comment: Neither func_1 nor func_2 use the wdw argument...

Comment: @P.Camilleri sorry you are right, that was a typo. wdw_size changes the size of the input given to the functions

Comment: Ok! But I think you corrected too much, and removed the second argument of partition? you might want to keep np.partitition(inp, 10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs, `np.partition` is implemented via **[Introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect)** - an algorithm with a worst-case performance of **O(n)**.

In a sentence, **Introselect** is a souped up version of Quick sort with a little help from [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians).

On the otherhand, `np.sort` is implemented using the plain old **Quick Sort**, which has a worst-case performance of **O(n^2)**.

So to compare the two, while `np.sort` only uses Quick sort and may end up with a **O(n^2**) as its worst-case performance, `np.partition` can avoid this by falling back on median of medians when necessary to always ensure a **O(n)**.

---

Not entirely sure but maybe `np.sort` is faster for small arrays just because `np.partition` has a larger overhead due to its more complex algorithm.

Comment: The graph supports the overhead idea.  And the O(n) increase.