# Finding K largest in nparray(value and argument)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, arguments

I would like to find the N biggest elements and their arguments in a numpy array.

I use partitions that i found but i cant get the 5 biggest in element in an numpy array. Here is an example:

```
a =[ 0.409,  0.355, -0.403,  0.307, -0.826, -0.66,  -1.582, -0.112, -0.244, -0.954]    
z = bn.argpartition(-a, 5)[:5]         
z = apodosi.argsort()[-5:]         
z = heapq.nlargest(5, a)
```

I get back the array a while I would like to get 0,1,3,5,7 as arguments and if possible their values. I am still new in programming!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A fast way to find the largest N elements in an numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337533/a-fast-way-to-find-the-largest-n-elements-in-an-numpy-array)

Comment: *"...I would like to get 0,1,3,5,7"*  I think you mean  [0, 1, 3, 7, 8].  I assume `bn` is `numpy`.  What is wrong with `z = bn.argpartition(-a, 5)[:5]` to get the indices of the five largest values?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably this:

```
array = [5,3,1,2,4,7,9,8,6]
array.sort(reverse=True) # [9,8,7,...,2,1]
greatest = array[0:5] # [9,8,7,6,5]
```

I imagine numpy arrays would work the same way.