# How to get indices of top-K values from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, keras, pytorch

Let suppose I have probabilities from a Pytorch or Keras predictions and result is with the softmax function

```
from scipy.special import softmax
probs = softmax(np.random.randn(20,10),1) # 20 instances and 10 class probabilities
probs
```

I want to find top-5 indices from this numpy array. All I want to do is to run a loop on the results something like:

```
for index in top_5_indices:
    if index in result:
        print('Found')
```

I'll get if my results are in top-5 results.

`Pytorch` has `top-k` function and I have seen `numpy.argpartition` but I have no idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

argpartition(a, k) function in numpy rearranges indices of input array a around the kth smallest element, so that all indices of smaller elements end up to the left, and all indices of bigger elements end up to the right. Not needing to sort all elements saves time: argpartition takes O(n) time, while argsort takes O(n log n) time.

So you can get the indices of 5 biggest elements like this:

```
np.argpartition(probs,-5)[-5:]
```

Comment: Would be more helpful if you explained your answer

Comment: `argpartition` uses heap sort, where it constructs a max heap, whose head, keeps track of the current kth smallest element. As you iterate through the array if you encounter an element smaller than the current head of the max heap, you knock the head off and push your new element onto the heap. Once done, the head of the heap will be the kth smallest element in your array. Vice-versa to find the kth largest with a min-heap.

Answer (score 4):

A little more expensive, but `argsort` would do:

```
idx = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[:,-5:]
```

If we are talking about pytorch:

```
probs = torch.from_numpy(softmax(np.random.randn(20,10),1))

values, idx = torch.topk(probs, k=5, axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers are correct, but I wanted to expand on them to provide a self-contained function that behaves exactly like `torch.topk` with pure `numpy`.

Here's the function (I've included the instructions inline):

```py
def topk(array, k, axis=-1, sorted=True):
    # Use np.argpartition is faster than np.argsort, but do not return the values in order
    # We use array.take because you can specify the axis
    partitioned_ind = (
        np.argpartition(array, -k, axis=axis)
        .take(indices=range(-k, 0), axis=axis)
    )
    # We use the newly selected indices to find the score of the top-k values
    partitioned_scores = np.take_along_axis(array, partitioned_ind, axis=axis)
    
    if sorted:
        # Since our top-k indices are not correctly ordered, we can sort them with argsort
        # only if sorted=True (otherwise we keep it in an arbitrary order)
        sorted_trunc_ind = np.flip(
            np.argsort(partitioned_scores, axis=axis), axis=axis
        )
        
        # We again use np.take_along_axis as we have an array of indices that we use to
        # decide which values to select
        ind = np.take_along_axis(partitioned_ind, sorted_trunc_ind, axis=axis)
        scores = np.take_along_axis(partitioned_scores, sorted_trunc_ind, axis=axis)
    else:
        ind = partitioned_ind
        scores = partitioned_scores
    
    return scores, ind
```

To verify the correctness, you can test it against torch:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(50, 50, 10, 10)

axis = 2  # Change this to any axis and it'll be fine

val_np, ind_np = topk(x, k=10, axis=axis)

val_pt, ind_pt = torch.topk(torch.tensor(x), k=10, dim=axis)

print("Values are same:", np.all(val_np == val_pt.numpy()))
print("Indices are same:", np.all(ind_np == ind_pt.numpy()))
```

- To be clear, `np.take_along_axis` is [recommended to be used with `np.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) for accessing the original value in the higher-dimension.
- `np.argpartition` is faster than `np.argsort` because it does not sort the entire array. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20177786/13837091) claims it takes `O(n)` instead of `O(n log

Comment: Nice answer :-)
Small typo in the code: 'scores = partition_scores' should be 'scores = partitioned_scores' in the else case of your numpy topk function.
(I cannot directly edit the post since it is would be a less than 6 characters edit... Sorry)