# Time complexity of torch.topk

Tags: python, pytorch

When m and n of n.topk(m) exceed 20 million and 200,000 respectively, the sorting becomes very slow(over 3 hours). I want to know the time complexity of torch.topk and improvement measures of the sorting.

```
topv, topi = outline.topk(beam_size)  # beam_size = 200,000, outline: 1 × 20,000,000
```

Comment: are you expecting this `topk` to happen on GPU or CPU?

Comment: sorry, it happens on CPU and I don't have a GPU for now.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, and I know you don't care about the answer after all this time, but it's the first one I found regarding the `torch.topk` complexity. And there is not a direct answer, so I did the measurements myself for anybody interested. I measured the execution times for many sizes of input.

This is what I got for constant `m`. Seconds on one axis, millions of input size on the other.

[image: constant k measurements]

This is what I got for a `m` dependent on `n`; it's random within the (0, n) range.

[image: dependent k measurements]

For the estimations I used a tool I wrote some years ago that estimates complexities: https://gitlab.com/damavrom/complexity-finder. This tool suggests the complexity that is closer to the real times.

So I believe that `torch.topk` is an implementation an `O(n+mlogn)` algorithm, that is the fastest that you can get on sorting. You can't go faster than that on general cases. So, you either decrease `n` or `m` or you buy faster hardware.

Comment: How is it possible for this algorithm to be differentiable? Wouldn't it need a smoothness/regularizer parameter? In my tests it preserves `grad_fn=<...Backward0>` for any `requires_grad` input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how pytorch implements `topk` for CPU tensors. However, since you are working on CPU, you can use existing partial sorting implementations for [numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10337643/1714410).

For example, using the [`bottleneck.argpartition`](https://bottleneck.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#bottleneck.argpartition):

```py
import bottleneck
with torch.no_grad():
  topi = bottleneck.argpartition(outline.numpy(), kth=beam_size)
topv = outline[topi]  # allow gradients to propagate through indexing
```

Note that the efficient implementation of `bottleneck.argpartition` does *not* sort the array and therefore you are guaranteed that `topv` are indeed larger than all other elements of the array, but the values in `topv` are not sorted and it might be the case that `topv[i] < topv[i+1]` for some `i`s.