# Python replacing max values in array

Tags: python, numpy, max

I have a 3D numpy array `A` of shape 10 x 5 x 3. I also have a vector `B` of length 3 (length of last axis of `A`). I want to compare each `A[:,:,i]` against `B[i]` where `i = 0:2` and replace all values `A[:,:,i] > B[i]` with `B[i]`.

Is there a way to achieve this without a for loop.

Edit: I tried the `argmax` across `i = 0:2` using a for loop
[python replace values in 2d numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984750/python-replace-values-in-2d-numpy-array)

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.minimum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) to accomplish this. It returns the element-wise minimum between two arrays. If the arrays are different sizes (such as in your case), then the arrays are automatically broadcast to the correct size prior to comparison.

```
A = numpy.random.rand(1,2,3)
# array([[[ 0.79188   ,  0.32707664,  0.18386629],
#         [ 0.4139146 ,  0.07259663,  0.47604274]]])

B = numpy.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])

C = numpy.minimum(A, B)
# array([[[ 0.1       ,  0.2       ,  0.18386629],
#         [ 0.1       ,  0.07259663,  0.3       ]]])
```

Or as suggested by [@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554038/python-replacing-max-values-in-array/36554078?noredirect=1#comment60709753_36554078) if you want to do in-place replacement:

```
numpy.minimum(A, B, out=A)
```

Comment: Or `numpy.minimum(A, B,out=A)`.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks for pointing that out. I always forget about that option!