# K-nearest points from two dataframes with GeoPandas

Tags: python, pandas, distance, geopandas

GeoPandas uses shapely under the hood. To get the nearest neighbor I saw the use of `nearest_points` [from shapely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222315/geopandas-find-nearest-point-in-other-dataframe). However, this approach does not include k-nearest points.

I needed to compute distances to nearest points from to GeoDataFrames and insert the distance into the GeoDataFrame containing the "from this point" data.

This is my approach using `GeoSeries.distance()` without using another package or library. Note that when `k == 1` the returned value essentially shows the distance to the nearest point. [There is also a GeoPandas-only solution for nearest point by @cd98 which inspired my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740046/calculate-distance-to-nearest-feature-with-geopandas).

This works well for my data, but I wonder if there is a better or faster approach or another benefit to use shapely or [sklearn.neighbors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369484/searching-for-k-nearest-points)?

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp

gdf1 > GeoDataFrame with point type geometry column - distance from this point
gdf2 > GeoDataFrame with point type geometry column - distance to this point

def knearest(from_points, to_points, k):
    distlist = to_points.distance(from_points)
    distlist.sort_values(ascending=True, inplace=True) # To have the closest ones first
    return distlist[:k].mean()

# looping through a list of nearest points
for Ks in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]:
    name = 'dist_to_closest_' + str(Ks) # to set column name
    gdf1[name] = gdf1.geometry.apply(knearest, args=(gdf2, closest_x))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes there is, but first, I must credit the University of Helsinki from [automating GIS process](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/index.html), here's [the source code](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/nearest-neighbor-faster.html). Here's how
first, read the data, for example, finding nearest bus stops for each building.

```
# Filepaths
stops = gpd.read_file('data/pt_stops_helsinki.gpkg')
buildings = read_gdf_from_zip('data/building_points_helsinki.zip')
```

define the function, here, you can adjust the `k_neighbors`

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np

def get_nearest(src_points, candidates, k_neighbors=1):
    """Find nearest neighbors for all source points from a set of candidate points"""

    # Create tree from the candidate points
    tree = BallTree(candidates, leaf_size=15, metric='haversine')

    # Find closest points and distances
    distances, indices = tree.query(src_points, k=k_neighbors)

    # Transpose to get distances and indices into arrays
    distances = distances.transpose()
    indices = indices.transpose()

    # Get closest indices and distances (i.e. array at index 0)
    # note: for the second closest points, you would take index 1, etc.
    closest = indices[0]
    closest_dist = distances[0]

    # Return indices and distances
    return (closest, closest_dist)


def nearest_neighbor(left_gdf, right_gdf, return_dist=False):
    """
    For each point in left_gdf, find closest point in right GeoDataFrame and return them.

    NOTICE: Assumes that the input Points are in WGS84 projection (lat/lon).
    """

    left_geom_col = left_gdf.geometry.name
    right_geom_col = right_gdf.geometry.name

    # Ensure that index in right gdf is formed of sequential numbers
    right = right_gdf.copy().reset_index(drop=True)

    # Parse coordinates from points and insert them into a numpy array as RADIANS
    left_radians = np.array(left_gdf[left_geom_col].apply(lambda geom: (geom.x * np.pi / 180, geom.y * np.pi / 180)).to_list())
    right_radians = np.array(right[right_geom_col].apply(lambda geom: (geom.x * np.pi / 180, geom.y * np.pi / 180)).to_list())

    # Find the nearest points
    # -----------------------
    # closest ==> index in right_gdf that corresponds to the closest point
    # dist ==> distance between the nearest neighbors (in meters)

    closest, dist = get_nearest(src_points=left_radians, candidates=right_radians)

    # Return points from right GeoDataFrame that are closest to points in left GeoDataFrame
    closest_points = right.loc[closest]

    # Ensure that the index corresponds the one in left_gdf
    closest_points = closest_points.reset_index(drop=True)

    # Add distance if requested
    if return_dist:
        # Convert to meters from radians
        earth_radius = 6371000  # meters
        closest_points['distance'] = dist * earth_radius

    return closest_points
```

Do the nearest neighbours analysis

```
# Find closest public transport stop for each building and get also the distance based on haversine distance
# Note: haversine distance which is implemented here is a bit slower than using e.g. 'euclidean' metric
# but useful as we get the distance between points in meters
closest_stops = nearest_neighbor(buildings, stops, return_dist=True)
```

now join the from and to data frame

```
# Rename the geometry of closest stops gdf so that we can easily identify it
closest_stops = closest_stops.rename(columns={'geometry': 'closest_stop_geom'})

# Merge the datasets by index (for this, it is good to use '.join()' -function)
buildings = buildings.join(closest_stops)
```

Comment: What about finding the closest line for each point?

Answer (score 1):

The answer above using Automating GIS-processes is really nice but there is an error when converting points as a numpy array as RADIANS. The latitude and longitude are reversed.

`left_radians = np.array(left_gdf[left_geom_col].apply(lambda geom: (geom.y * np.pi / 180, geom.x * np.pi / 180)).to_list())`

Indeed Points are given with (lat, lon) but the longitude correspond the x-axis of a plan or a sphere and the latitude to the y-axis.

Answer (score 1):

If your data are in grid coordinates, then the approach is a bit leaner, but with one key gotcha.

Building on [sutan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63636266/9249533) and streamlining the block from the Uni Helsinki...

To get multiple neighbors, you edit the k_neighbors argument....and must ALSO hard code vars within the body of the function (see my additions below 'closest' and 'closest_dist') AND add them to the return statement.

Thus, if you want the 2 closest points, it looks like:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import numpy as np

def get_nearest(src_points, candidates, k_neighbors=2):
    """
    Find nearest neighbors for all source points from a set of candidate points
    modified from: https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/nearest-neighbor-faster.html
    """
    

    # Create tree from the candidate points
    tree = BallTree(candidates, leaf_size=15, metric='euclidean')

    # Find closest points and distances
    distances, indices = tree.query(src_points, k=k_neighbors)

    # Transpose to get distances and indices into arrays
    distances = distances.transpose()
    indices = indices.transpose()

    # Get closest indices and distances (i.e. array at index 0)
    # note: for the second closest points, you would take index 1, etc.
    closest = indices[0]
    closest_dist = distances[0]
    closest_second = indices[1] # *manually add per comment above*
    closest_second_dist = distances[1] # *manually add per comment above*

    # Return indices and distances
    return (closest, closest_dist, closest_sec, closest_sec_dist)
```

The inputs are lists of (x,y) tuples. Thus, since (by question title) your data is in a GeoDataframe:

```
# easier to read
in_pts = [(row.geometry.x, row.geometry.y) for idx, row in gdf1.iterrows()]
qry_pts = [(row.geometry.x, row.geometry.y) for idx, row in gdf2.iterrows()]

# faster (by about 7X)
in_pts = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(gdf1.geometry.x , gdf1.geometry.y)]
qry_pts =  [(x,y) for x,y in zip(gdf2.geometry.x , gdf2.geometry.y)]
```

I'm not interested in distances, so instead of commenting out of the function,  I run:

```
idx_nearest, _, idx_2ndnearest, _ = get_nearest(in_pts, qry_pts)
```

and get two arrays of the same length of in_pts that, respectively, contain index values of the closest and second closest points from the original geodataframe for qry_pts.

Answer (score 0):

Great solution! If you are using [Automating GIS-processes](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/nearest-neighbor-faster.html)  solution, make sure to reset the index of buildings geoDataFrame before join (only if you are using a subset of left_gdf).

```
buildings.insert(0, 'Number', range(0,len(buildings)))

buildings.set_index('Number' , inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers before I have a **all-in-one** solution for you which takes **two geopandas.DataFrames** as input and searches for the **nearest k-neighbors**.

```
def get_nearest_neighbors(gdf1, gdf2, k_neighbors=2):
'''
Find k nearest neighbors for all source points from a set of candidate points
modified from: https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/nearest-neighbor-faster.html    

Parameters
----------
gdf1 : geopandas.DataFrame
    Geometries to search from.
gdf2 : geopandas.DataFrame
    Geoemtries to be searched.
k_neighbors : int, optional
    Number of nearest neighbors. The default is 2.

Returns
-------
gdf_final : geopandas.DataFrame
    gdf1 with distance, index and all other columns from gdf2.
'''

src_points = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(gdf1.geometry.x , gdf1.geometry.y)]
candidates =  [(x,y) for x,y in zip(gdf2.geometry.x , gdf2.geometry.y)]

# Create tree from the candidate points
tree = BallTree(candidates, leaf_size=15, metric='euclidean')

# Find closest points and distances
distances, indices = tree.query(src_points, k=k_neighbors)

# Transpose to get distances and indices into arrays
distances = distances.transpose()
indices = indices.transpose()

closest_gdfs = []
for k in np.arange(k_neighbors):
    gdf_new = gdf2.iloc[indices[k]].reset_index()
    gdf_new['distance'] =  distances[k]
    gdf_new = gdf_new.add_suffix(f'_{k+1}')
    closest_gdfs.append(gdf_new)
    
closest_gdfs.insert(0,gdf1)    
gdf_final = pd.concat(closest_gdfs,axis=1)

return gdf_final
```