# Finding the Index of sorted elements in Python Array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I have seen answers to the question:
*Is it possible to arrange a numpy array (or python list) by using the indexes of the elements in decreasing order?* (eg. [Finding the Index of N biggest elements in Python Array / List Efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787650/finding-the-index-of-n-biggest-elements-in-python-array-list-efficiently))

A very concise answer seems to be (from above link):

```
L = array([4, 1, 0, 8, 5, 2])
sorted(range(len(L)), key=lambda i:L[i])
```

This gives the position (in the original array) of the sorted elements.

8 --> 3
5 --> 4
4 --> 0
2 --> 5
1 --> 1
0 --> 2

So the answer is:

```
[3, 4, 0, 5, 1, 2]
```

---

What I am after is the position (in the sorted array) of the elements:

```
L = array([4, 1, 0, 8, 5, 2])
```

8 --> 0
 5 --> 1
 4 --> 2
 2 --> 3
 1 --> 4
 0 --> 5

So I want :

```
[2, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3]
```

I realise I could take the answer from the first example, and use that to get what I want (with a bit more fiddling) but is there a short cut?

Efficiency is not a concern. I just need something that gives me the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses. I like the use of the lambda expression twice to get what I what.  
Now is someone can just explain (in really simple terms for a tyro) how that line of code actually operates I will be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use your technique twice to get the indices in the sorted list:

```
A=[4, 1, 0, 8, 5, 2]
B=sorted(range(len(A)),key=lambda x:A[x],reverse=True)
C=sorted(range(len(A)),key=lambda x:B[x])
print C
```

prints

```
[2, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3]
```

### Explanation

The idea is that the first iteration produces a list:

```
B = [3, 4, 0, 5, 1, 2]
```

giving the locations in the original list of the sorted sequence.

In other words, A[3]=8 is the largest element in the original list, A[4]=5 is the next largest, etc.

The second stage then sorts these indices in B back into the order 0,1,2,3,4,5 and produces C which contains the index in the list B.

It may help to think of B as sorting the list into descending order, and C as reversing the sort back into the original unsorted order, while keeping track of the indices in the sorted list.

Comment: Maybe I spoke too soon?  
Ok with: A=[4, 1, 0, 8, 5, 2]  
Tried A=[14, 15, 30, 18, 11, 21]

Comment: @RustyC You are quite right, I've edited the answer to behave better

Answer (score 3):

EDIT when I first read the question, I thought you were looking for [numpy.argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).

Having read it again, I realized I misread.

[scipy.stats.rankdata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rankdata.html) is what you're looking for (offset by 1, and reversed)

```
(scipy.stats.rankdata([4, 1, 0, 8, 5, 2])-1)[::-1]
=> array([ 2.,  4.,  5.,  0.,  1.,  3.])
```

(Original *wrong* answer, referring to argsort:)

```
from numpy import array, argsort
L = array([4, 1, 0, 8, 5, 2])
argsort(L)
=> array([2, 1, 5, 0, 4, 3])
```

Comment: Isn't this giving the wrong answer?  He wants [2,4,5,0,1,3] as the answer?

Comment: This does the thing from the first version (but in reverse), which he doesn't want.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz right, I misread the question. I fixed my answer now.

Comment: You might want to add the `method='ordinal'` flag.

Answer (score -1):

are you using numpy? if so, use `numpy.argsort`

```
import numpy as np
fakedata = np.array([40,20,60,50,10,20,80,30,50,40])
sorted_index = np.argsort(fakedata)
print(sorted_index)
print(fakedata[sorted_index])
[4 1 5 7 0 9 3 8 2 6] # sorted index
[10 20 20 30 40 40 50 50 60 80] # values selected by the sorted index
```

Comment: This is an answer to the first part of my question - the one that has already been answered elsewhere. I want:
_For each element in the original list give me its position in the sorted list_.
Not:
_For each element in the sorted list give me its position in the original list._