# Get indices of the top N values of a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list say `a = [5,3,1,4,10]`. I need to get indices of the top two values of the list, that is for `5` and `10` I would get `[0, 4]`. Is there a one-liner that Python offers for such a case?

Comment: When you say 'values', do you only mean ints? floats? numeric? string? arbitrary object? It's better to give an example list that tests mixed types.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

```
sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: a[i])[-2:]
```

or

```
sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: a[i], reverse=True)[:2]
```

or

```
import operator

zip(*sorted(enumerate(a), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))[0][-2:]
```

or (for long lists), consider using [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest)

```
zip(*heapq.nlargest(2, enumerate(a), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))[0]
```

Comment: In Python 3, zip returns an iterable object. So, the last one would have slight modification: `list(zip(...))[0]`

Answer (score 35):

Just a NumPy alternative:

```
import numpy as np

top_2_idx = np.argsort(a)[-2:]
top_2_values = [a[i] for i in top_2_idx]
```

Comment: If you're willing to use `numpy`, it's more efficient to use `argpartition` than `argsort`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23734295/388951

Answer (score 1):

As [danvk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388951/danvk) suggested, we can use [argpartion](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) method of numpy for good efficiency like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23734295/8961642).

If we need two top indexes, we can use this sample code:

```
import numpy as np
# Find two top indexes
ind = np.argpartition(a, -2)[-2:]
# Sort them
ind = ind[np.argsort(a[ind])]
```