# I have need the N minimum (index) values in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, minimum

Hi I have an array with X amount of values in it I would like to locate the indexs of the ten smallest values. In this link they calculated the maximum effectively, [How to get indices of N maximum values in a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-to-get-the-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array)
however I cant comment on links yet so I'm having to repost the question.

I'm not sure which indices i need to change to achieve the minimum and not the maximum values.
This is their code

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 5])

In [3]: arr.argsort()[-3:][::-1]
Out[3]: array([4, 3, 1])
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you call

```
arr.argsort()[:3]
```

It will give you the indices of the 3 smallest elements.

```
array([0, 2, 1], dtype=int64)
```

So, for `n`, you should call

```
arr.argsort()[:n]
```

Answer (score 31):

Since this question was posted, numpy has updated to include a faster way of selecting the smallest elements from an array using [`argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.8.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html). It was first included in Numpy 1.8.

Using [snarly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23734295/1342354) as inspiration, we can quickly find the `k=3` smallest elements:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 5])

In [3]: k = 3

In [4]: ind = np.argpartition(arr, k)[:k]

In [5]: ind
Out[5]: array([0, 2, 1])

In [6]: arr[ind]
Out[6]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

This will run in O(n) time because it does not need to do a full sort. If you need your answers sorted (**Note:** in this case the output array was in sorted order but that is not guaranteed) you can sort the output:

```
In [7]: sorted(arr[ind])
Out[7]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

This runs on O(n + k log k) because the sorting takes place on the smaller
output list.

Answer (score 8):

I don't guarantee that this will be faster, but a *better algorithm* would rely on `heapq`.

```
import heapq
indices = heapq.nsmallest(10,np.nditer(arr),key=arr.__getitem__)
```

This should work in approximately `O(N)` operations whereas using `argsort` would take `O(NlogN)` operations.  However, the other is pushed into highly optimized C, so it might still perform better.  To know for sure, you'd need to run some tests on your actual data.

Comment: o yeah, this works as well. I tried to use it before but was missing some of it and it got a bit complicated, but it works now thanks :]

Comment: Works for me as well. However, in my case it is about 20 times slower than the pure numpy solution

Answer (score 4):

Just don't reverse the sort results.

```
In [164]: a = numpy.random.random(20)

In [165]: a
Out[165]: 
array([ 0.63261763,  0.01718228,  0.42679479,  0.04449562,  0.19160089,
        0.29653725,  0.93946388,  0.39915215,  0.56751034,  0.33210873,
        0.17521395,  0.49573607,  0.84587652,  0.73638224,  0.36303797,
        0.2150837 ,  0.51665416,  0.47111993,  0.79984964,  0.89231776])
```

Sorted:

```
In [166]: a.argsort()
Out[166]: 
array([ 1,  3, 10,  4, 15,  5,  9, 14,  7,  2, 17, 11, 16,  8,  0, 13, 18,
       12, 19,  6])
```

First ten:

```
In [168]: a.argsort()[:10]
Out[168]: array([ 1,  3, 10,  4, 15,  5,  9, 14,  7,  2])
```

Answer (score 2):

This code save 20 index of maximum element of `split_list` in `Twenty_Maximum`:

```
Twenty_Maximum = split_list.argsort()[-20:]
```

against this code save 20 index of minimum element of `split_list` in `Twenty_Minimum`:

```
Twenty_Minimum = split_list.argsort()[:20]
```