# Numpy: give back an array with the n entries closest to a given number

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a numpy array `arr` and I want to create a new array with the `n` elements of the old one, that are the closest to a given number `x`. I've found a helpful answer here ([I have need the N minimum (index) values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817948/i-have-need-the-n-minimum-index-values-in-a-numpy-array)), but my code seems very clumsy (I'm a beginner in Python):

```
def give_array_with_closest(x, n, arr):
    newar = np.absolute(arr - (np.ones(len(arr)) * x)) #Subtract x from all array entries and take absolute value, so that the lowest entries are the ones closest to x
    indexar = (newar).argsort()[:n] #get array with indices from n lowest entries of newar
    result = np.empty(n)
    for i in range(n):
        result[i] = arr[indexar[i]]
    return result
```

Since I'm not interested in the indices but only the actual entries, maybe the solution of the other question isn't the best in this case. Is there a more efficient and simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It has been mentioned already that you don't need the for-loop to get the values for the indices, you can simply use the result of `argsort` to index the array (at least if your arrays are 1D).
- But you also don't need to `sort` the full array. You could simply use [`argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html). That *could* be faster than sorting.
- As additional point: You can use vectorized operations like `arr - 1`. That will subtract one from each element without needing to create a new array manually (like your `np.ones(len(arr))`).

So putting these together:

```
def give_array_with_closest(x, n, arr):
    indexarr = np.argpartition(abs(arr - x), n)[:n]
    return arr[indexarr]
```

And the test:

```
>>> give_array_with_closest(2, 3, np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
array([2, 3, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create new array one-call by providing indices:

```
def give_array_with_closest2(x, n, arr):
    newar = np.absolute(arr - (np.ones(len(arr)) * x)) 
    return arr[(newar).argsort()[:n]]
```

So actually this is the same code, but more elegant and probably faster.