# Determine indices of N number of non-zero minimum values in array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, minimum

I have an array of x size and need to determine the indices of n of the smallest values. I found this link ([I have need the N minimum (index) values in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817948/i-have-need-the-n-minimum-index-values-in-a-numpy-array)) discussing how to get multiple minimum values but it doesn't work as well when my array has zeros in it.

For example:

```
x = [10, 12, 11, 9, 0, 1, 15, 4, 10]
n = 3
```

I need to find the indices of the 3 lowest non-zero values so the result would be

```
non_zero_min_ind = [5, 7, 3]
```

They don't need to be be in any order. I am trying to do this in python 3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why does it have to use numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.argsort(x)
y[np.array(x)[y]!=0][:n]

array([5, 7, 3])
```

Comment: What if There are more than one 0?