# How to find the index of n largest elements in a list or np.array, Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

Is there a built-in function or a very simple way of finding the index of n largest elements in a list or a numpy array?

```
K = [1,2,2,4,5,5,6,10]
```

Find the index of the largest 5 elements?

I count the duplicates more than once, and the output should be a list of the indices of those largest numbers

Comment: what is your expected output here?

Comment: are you counting duplicates more than once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get indices of N maximum values in a numpy array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-to-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: what about `[1,2,2,4,5,10,5,6,10]`, what would be the output in this case?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
>>> K
[4, 5, 1, 6, 2, 5, 2, 10]
>>> sorted(range(len(K)), key=lambda x: K[x])
[2, 4, 6, 0, 1, 5, 3, 7]
>>> sorted(range(len(K)), key=lambda x: K[x])[-5:]
[0, 1, 5, 3, 7]
```

or using `numpy`, you can use `argsort`:

```
>>> np.argsort(K)[-5:]
array([0, 1, 5, 3, 7])
```

`argsort` is also a method:

```
>>> K = np.array(K)
>>> K.argsort()[-5:]
array([0, 1, 5, 3, 7])
>>> K[K.argsort()[-5:]]
array([ 4,  5,  5,  6, 10])
```

Comment: Alternatively `import heapq;heapq.nlargest(n, range(len(K)), key=lambda x: K[x])`

Comment: This is not optimal to sort it for very big list since it may take O(n^2), while you're supposed to solved this in a linear time.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following code,

```
 N=5
 K = [1,10,2,4,5,5,6,2]
 #store list in tmp to retrieve index
 tmp=list(K)
 #sort list so that largest elements are on the far right
 K.sort()
 #To get the 5 largest elements
 print K[-N:]
 #To get the 5th largest element
 print K[-N]
 #get index of the 5th largest element
 print tmp.index(K[-N])
```

If you wish to ignore duplicates, then use set() as follows,

```
 N=5
 K = [1,10,2,4,5,5,6,2]
 #store list in tmp to retrieve index
 tmp=list(K)
 #sort list so that largest elements are on the far right
 K.sort()
 #Putting the list to a set removes duplicates
 K=set(K)
 #change K back to list since set does not support indexing
 K=list(K)
 #To get the 5 largest elements
 print K[-N:]
 #To get the 5th largest element
 print K[-N]
 #get index of the 5th largest element
 print tmp.index(K[-N])
```

Hopefully one of them covers your question :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
K = [1,2,2,4,5,5,6,10]
num = 5
print 'K %s.' % (sorted(K, reverse=True)[:num])
```

Comment: this gives the values themselves but not their index

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency, numpy partition is much more efficient for large array.
There is no need to sort fully.

"All elements smaller than the k-th element are moved before this element and all equal or greater are moved behind it. The ordering of the elements in the two partitions is undefined."

Comment: I was about to add this as an answer. What I think @cosine means is to use [np.argpartition](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) rather than np.argsort (as in @DSM's answer). So `np.argpartition(K,-5)[-5:]` returns [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], the *indexes* of the five largest values. Using those indexes on K, `np.array(K)[ np.argpartition(K,-5)[-5:] ]` returns [ 4,  5,  5,  6, 10], the actual 5 largest values (which you could also get directly using `np.partition(K,-5)[-5:]`).

Answer (score 0):

`import headq`

Then use function `nlargest()`

Comment: Dear JimmyC, You're right, this is the best way to do it in python. Yet your answer received downvotes. I suppose it's because there are a few ways in which your answer could be improved: (1) You wrote `headq` instead of `heapq`. (2) Please write full English sentences. (3) Please give an example use. (4) You could also link to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest