# Next argmax values in python

Tags: python

I have a function that returns the argmax from a large 2d array

```
getMax = np.argmax(dist, axis=1)
```

However I want to get the next biggest values, is there a way of removing the getMax values from the original array and then performing argmax again?

Comment: If you don't just need the second largest element, but maybe also the third and so on, the following might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878715/how-to-find-the-index-of-n-largest-elements-in-a-list-or-np-array-python

Comment: Do you actually want to remove the largest, or do you want to just find the next largest?

Comment: @Joel find the next largest

Comment: Check my answer --- I don't have numpy on the computer I'm on right now, so can't bug check

Comment: @Joel I'm sorry to say but I can't change the order for what I need it for

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the command `np.argsort(a, axis=-1, kind='quicksort', order=None)`, but with appropriate choice of arguments (below).

here is the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).  Note  "It returns an array of indices of the same shape as a that index data along the given axis in sorted order."

The default order is small to large.  So sort with `-dist` (for quick coding).  Caution: doing `-dist` causes a new array to be generated which you may care about if `dist` is huge.  See bottom of post for a better alternative there.

Here is an example:

```
x = np.array([[1,2,5,0],[5,7,2,3]])
L = np.argsort(-x, axis=1)

print L
[[2 1 0 3]
 [1 0 3 2]]

x  
array([[1, 2, 5, 0],
   [5, 7, 2, 3]])
```

So the n'th entry in a row of `L` gives the locations of the n'th largest element of `x`.

`x` is unchanged.

`L[:,0]` will give the same output as `np.argmax(x)`

```
L[:,0]
array([2, 1])

np.argmax(x,axis=1)
array([2, 1])
```

and `L[:,1]` will give the same as a hypothetical `argsecondmax(x)`

```
L[:,1]
array([1, 0])
```

If you don't want to generate a new list, so you don't want to use `-x`:

```
L = np.argsort(x, axis=1)

print L
[[3 0 1 2]
 [2 3 0 1]]

L[:,-1]
array([2, 1])

L[:,-2]
array([1, 0])
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say but order is important, I cannot change the order

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  The sorting `np.argsort(dist)` gives a list of locations from location of smallest to location of largest.  So `np.argsort(-dist)` gives the list of locations of smallest to largest of `-dist`.  So it's the locations of largest to smallest of `dist`.   It doesn't change the order of `dist` in any way.

Comment: I've just realised this, however when I use it, it returns an array full of zeros rather than what it should

Comment: Can you edit your question to give a minimal example and expected output?

Comment: I have solved it, it was an error later in the code. Thank you Joel!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66863/discussion-between-joel-and-sprout).

Answer (score 4):

If speed is important to you, using argpartition rather than argsort could be useful.

For example, to return the n largest elements from a list:

```
import numpy as np 

l = np.random.random_integer(0, 100, 1e6)

top_n_1 = l[np.argsort(-l)[0:n]]
top_n_2 = l[np.argpartition(l, -n)[-n:]]
```

The `%timeit` function in ipython reports
`10 loops, best of 3: 56.9 ms per loop` for `top_n_1` and `100 loops, best of 3: 8.06 ms per loop` for `top_n_2`.

I hope this is useful.