# Pandas dataframe: return row AND column of maximum value(s)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which all values are of the same variety (e.g. a correlation matrix -- but where we expect a unique maximum). I'd like to return the row and the column of the maximum of this matrix.

I can get the max across rows *or* columns by changing the first argument of

```
df.idxmax()
```

however I haven't found a suitable way to return the row/column index of the max of the whole dataframe.

For example, I can do this in numpy:

```
>>>npa = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,9,5],[6,7,8]])
>>>np.where(npa == np.amax(npa))
(array([1]), array([1]))
```

But when I try something similar in pandas:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,9,5],[6,7,8]],columns=list('abc'),index=list('def'))
>>>df.where(df == df.max().max())
    a   b   c
d NaN NaN NaN
e NaN   9 NaN
f NaN NaN NaN
```

At a second level, **what I acutally want to do is to return the rows and columns of the top n values**, e.g. as a Series.

E.g. for the above I'd like a function which does:

```
>>>topn(df,3)
b e
c f
b f
dtype: object
>>>type(topn(df,3))
pandas.core.series.Series
```

or even just

```
>>>topn(df,3)
(['b','c','b'],['e','f','f'])
```

a la numpy.where()

Comment: Should `topn(df,3)` return `(['b','c','a'],['e','f','f'])` or `(['b','c','b'],['e','f','f'])`

Comment: the latter. `df['a']['f']` = 6 while `df['b']['f']` = 7

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the first part:

```
npa = df.as_matrix()   
cols,indx = np.where(npa == np.amax(npa))
([df.columns[c] for c in cols],[df.index[c] for c in indx])
```

Now I need a way to get the top n. One naive idea is to copy the array, and iteratively replace the top values with `NaN` grabbing index as you go. Seems inefficient. Is there a better way to get the top n values of a numpy array? Fortunately, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23734295/695804) there is, through `argpartition`, but we have to use flattened indexing.

```
def topn(df,n):
    npa = df.as_matrix()   
    topn_ind = np.argpartition(npa,-n,None)[-n:] #flatend ind, unsorted
    topn_ind = topn_ind[np.argsort(npa.flat[topn_ind])][::-1] #arg sort in descending order
    cols,indx = np.unravel_index(topn_ind,npa.shape,'F') #unflatten, using column-major ordering
    return ([df.columns[c] for c in cols],[df.index[i] for i in indx])
```

Trying this on the example:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,9,5],[6,7,8]],columns=list('abc'),index=list('def'))
>>>topn(df,3)
(['b', 'c', 'b'], ['e', 'f', 'f'])
```

As desired. Mind you the sorting was not originally asked for, but provides little overhead if `n` is not large.

Comment: this seems not to work for arbitrary DataFrames, `topn(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(40,5)),4)` gives me an `IndexError: index out of bounds` error

Answer (score 3):

what you want to use is `stack`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,9,5],[6,7,8]],columns=list('abc'),index=list('def'))
df = df.stack()
df.sort(ascending=False)
df.head(4)

e  b    9
f  c    8
   b    7
   a    6
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess for what you are trying to do a DataFrame might not be the best choice, since the idea of the columns in the DataFrame is to hold independent data.

```
>>> def topn(df,n):
       # pull the data ouit of the DataFrame
       # and flatten it to an array
       vals = df.values.flatten(order='F')
       # next we sort the array and store the sort mask
       p = np.argsort(vals)
       # create two arrays with the column names and indexes
       # in the same order as vals
       cols = np.array([[col]*len(df.index) for col in df.columns]).flatten()
       idxs = np.array([list(df.index) for idx in df.index]).flatten()
       # sort and return cols, and idxs
       return cols[p][:-(n+1):-1],idxs[p][:-(n+1):-1]

>>> topn(df,3)
(array(['b', 'c', 'b'], 
      dtype='|S1'),
 array(['e', 'f', 'f'], 
      dtype='|S1'))


>>> %timeit(topn(df,3))
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.9 µs per loop
```

watsonics solution takes slightly less

```
%timeit(topn(df,3))
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.6 µs per loop
```

but way faster than stack

```
def topStack(df,n):
    df = df.stack()
    df.sort(ascending=False)
    return df.head(n)

 %timeit(topStack(df,3))
 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loop
```

Comment: sorry but this is wrong in several ways and doesn't address my question. i added some explicit examples to make it more clear. also fyi `df.describe().loc['max']` is much easier done as `df.max()`

Comment: hey @greole, cool a completely different way! for the communities benefit can you explain a bit about your code? some lines are somewhat cryptic, e.g. `*[[col]*len(df) for col in df.columns])` and `MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(cols,val.index))` maybe take it piece by piece or supplement with comments? also if you package this as a function, we can compare runtimes... thanks for the different way!

Comment: @watsonic ok I refactored it a bit and added some comments. Avoiding to operate on DataFrame it self gave a huge speed benefit.