# How to get Top 3 or Top N predictions using sklearn's SGDClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
arr=['dogs cats lions','apple pineapple orange','water fire earth air', 'sodium potassium calcium']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(arr)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
Y = ['animals', 'fruits', 'elements','chemicals']
T=["eating apple roasted in fire and enjoying fresh air"]
test = vectorizer.transform(T)
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='log')
clf.fit(X,Y)
x=clf.predict(test)
#prints: elements
```

In the above code, `clf.predict()` prints only 1 best prediction for a sample from **list X**.
I am interested in **top 3 predictions** for a particular sample in the **list X**, i know the function `predict_proba`/`predict_log_proba` returns a list of all probabilities for each feature in **list Y**, but it has to sorted and then associated with the features in list Y before getting the **top 3 results**.
Is there any direct and efficient way?

Comment: @user1269942: Very helpful addition there! However, I did not totally understand the function of the "truths" variable. Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no built-in function, but what is wrong with

```
probs = clf.predict_proba(test)
best_n = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[-n:]
```

### ?

As suggested by one of the comment, should change `[-n:]` to `[:,-n:]`

```
probs = clf.predict_proba(test)
best_n = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[:,-n:]
```

Comment: No names associated with the corresponding probability!

Comment: clf.classes_ provides these.

Comment: Shouldn't the slicing be  `best_n = np.argsort(probs, axis=1)[:, -n:]` ?

Comment: Hey @AndreasMueller, exactly how would you map the clf.classes_ to the probs? I am new to Python and have spent the last 90 minutes trying to figure out how to map the indices of the classes to the actual classes...thanks!

Comment: one more question: the slicing with best_n provides 3rd best, 2nd best, then 1st best. how could you reverse the order so it's 1st, 2nd, then 3rd? thanks again!

Comment: woohoo once again figured it out! feel free to delete these comments if they seem irrelevant, but i am thinking they might help others.
`best_n = np.argsort(-probs, axis = 1)[:, :3]`

Comment: I seem to be getting the right results but my is `[:,-n:]` the correct slicing instead of `[-n:]`?

Answer (score 11):

I know this has been answered...but I can add a bit more...

```
#both preds and truths are same shape m by n (m is number of predictions and n is number of classes)
def top_n_accuracy(preds, truths, n):
    best_n = np.argsort(preds, axis=1)[:,-n:]
    ts = np.argmax(truths, axis=1)
    successes = 0
    for i in range(ts.shape[0]):
      if ts[i] in best_n[i,:]:
        successes += 1
    return float(successes)/ts.shape[0]
```

It's quick and dirty but I find it useful. One can add their own error checking, etc..

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully, [Andreas](https://stackexchange.com/users/344360/andreas-mueller) will help with this. predict_probs is not available when loss='hinge'. To get top n class when loss='hinge' do:

```
calibrated_clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(clfSDG, cv=3, method='sigmoid')
model = calibrated_clf.fit(train.data, train.label)

probs = model.predict_proba(test_data)
sorted( zip( calibrated_clf.classes_, probs[0] ), key=lambda x:x[1] )[-n:]
```

Not sure if clfSDG.predict and calibrated_clf.predict will always predict the same class.

Comment: Given that log-loss for SGDClassifier is OvR, you could also just rank by ``decision_function`` and it wouldn't really be worse in any way. Using CalibratedClassifierCV is probably better, but orthogonal to the question. I would use LogisticRegression(multiclass='multinomial').

Answer (score 2):

`argsort` gives results in ascending order, if you want to save yourself with unusual loops or confusion you can use a simple trick.

```
probs = clf.predict_proba(test)
best_n = np.argsort(-probs, axis=1)[:, :n]
```

Negating the probabilities will turn smallest to largest and hence you can take top-n results in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

As @FredFoo described in [How do I get indices of N maximum values in a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-do-i-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array/38884051) a faster method would be to use [`argpartition`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html).

> Newer NumPy versions (1.8 and up) have a function called `argpartition`
> for this. To get the indices of the four largest elements, do

```
>>> a = np.array([9, 4, 4, 3, 3, 9, 0, 4, 6, 0])
>>> a array([9, 4, 4, 3, 3, 9, 0, 4, 6, 0])
>>> ind = np.argpartition(a, -4)[-4:]
>>> ind array([1, 5, 8, 0])
>>> a[ind] array([4, 9, 6, 9])
```

> Unlike `argsort`, this function runs in linear time in the worst case, but the returned indices are not
> sorted, as can be seen from the result of evaluating `a[ind]`. If you
> need that too, sort them afterwards:

```
>>> ind[np.argsort(a[ind])] array([1, 8, 5, 0])
```

> To get the `top-k` elements in sorted order in this way takes `O(n + k log k)` time.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that outputs a dataframe with the top n predictions and their probabilities, and ties it back to class names. Hope this is helpful!

```
def return_top_n_pred_prob_df(n, model, X_test, column_name):
  predictions = model.predict_proba(X_test)
  preds_idx = np.argsort(-predictions) 
  classes = pd.DataFrame(model.classes_, columns=['class_name'])
  classes.reset_index(inplace=True)
  top_n_preds = pd.DataFrame()
  for i in range(n):
        top_n_preds[column_name + '_prediction_{}_num'.format(i)] =     [preds_idx[doc][i] for doc in range(len(X_test))]
    top_n_preds[column_name + '_prediction_{}_probability'.format(i)] = [predictions[doc][preds_idx[doc][i]] for doc in range(len(X_test))]
    top_n_preds = top_n_preds.merge(classes, how='left', left_on= column_name + '_prediction_{}_num'.format(i), right_on='index')
    top_n_preds = top_n_preds.rename(columns={'class_name': column_name + '_prediction_{}'.format(i)})
    try: top_n_preds.drop(columns=['index', column_name + '_prediction_{}_num'.format(i)], inplace=True) 
    except: pass
  return top_n_preds
```