# How to get matrix of indices of N maximum values in each row of an numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Related to [How to get indices of N maximum values in a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6910641/297797), I have a numpy matrix `a`, and I would like to produce the array whose *i*-th row is the column indices of the top *N* elements of the *i*-th row of `a`.

Following the top-voted answer to the linked question, adapting it for arrays, here is what I have so far (using *N*=4):

```
>>> a
array([[9, 4, 4, 3, 3, 9, 0, 4, 6, 0],
       [3, 4, 6, 9, 5, 7, 1, 2, 8, 4]])
>>> ind=np.argpartition(a,-4)[:,-4:]
>>> ind
array([[1, 5, 8, 0],
       [2, 3, 8, 5]])
>>> rows=np.transpose([np.arange(a.shape[0])])
>>> rows
array([[0],
       [1]])
>>> ind_sorted = ind[rows,np.argsort(a[rows,ind])]
>>> ind_sorted
array([[1, 8, 5, 0],
       [2, 5, 8, 3]])
```

This works, but seems to be not very (num)pythonic.  I'm sure there's a better way to do the indexing that doesn't require a dummy array.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Slicing the last four elements of the order index by row seems to be working:

```
a.argsort(axis = 1)[:, -4:]

# array([[7, 8, 0, 5],
#        [2, 5, 8, 3]])
```

The tie method is not defined, so there will be some difference between `1` and `7` as well as the order of `0` and `5`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I had wanted the `argpartition` method because I was worried about the time to sort the whole matrix (it's about 150x150).  Should I be, or is that premature optimization?

Comment: If your matrix is of 150 * 150 dimension, I would not worry about the time. With that being said, the sorting algorithm should be optimized for any high level language if provided, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am posting code for getting indices for top 2 values in each row.

```
Unsorted_Array = np.array ([[23, 56, 12, 24], [6, 36, 9, 99], [24, 11, 87, 9], [7,29,103, 5]])
Index_of_Top_2_Values_of_EachRow = np.argsort(Unsorted_Array,axis = 1)[:,-2:]
print(Index_of_Top_2_Values_of_EachRow)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing.  Other than changing 4 to 2, can you explain how this answer is different than the one posted by Psidom four years ago?