# Find max 2 (or n) values in a column from a csv file(python)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to find the max values in a column imported from a csv file.
For the max value i used this code(I saw it prints also the value of the left column related to the max, why?):

```
data = pandas.read_csv(dataset, sep=',', usecols=[1])
maxValue=data.max(axis=0)[1]
```

How can i get the first 2 (or n) max values(using pandas, scipy or numpy)?
I tried so, but doesn't work:

```
secondM=data[data[1]!=maxValue][data[1]].max()
```

Comment: See if this solves it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-to-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** more general solution for showing N largest values for **all** columns:

```
In [393]: df
Out[393]:
   a  b  c
0  2  9  9
1  4  8  0
2  8  6  3
3  0  8  3
4  3  6  0

In [394]: N = 2
     ...: pd.DataFrame([df[c].nlargest(N).values.tolist() for c in df.columns],
     ...:              index=df.columns,
     ...:              columns=['{}_largest'.format(i) for i in range(1, N+1)]).T
     ...:
Out[394]:
           a  b  c
1_largest  8  9  9
2_largest  4  8  3

In [395]: N = 3
     ...: pd.DataFrame([df[c].nlargest(N).values.tolist() for c in df.columns],
     ...:              index=df.columns,
     ...:              columns=['{}_largest'.format(i) for i in range(1, N+1)]).T
     ...:
Out[395]:
           a  b  c
1_largest  8  9  9
2_largest  4  8  3
3_largest  3  8  3
```

**OLD answer:**

I assume that you want to have 2 (or n) largest values for a single column (as you used `usecols=[1]`):

```
In [279]: df
Out[279]:
   a  b  c
0  1  0  2
1  0  7  7
2  7  7  9
3  5  1  6
4  7  0  3
5  4  0  4
6  0  6  1
7  8  3  6
8  2  8  8
9  2  9  2

In [280]: df['a'].nlargest(2)
Out[280]:
7    8
2    7
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

**NOTE:** if your CSV file doesn't have labels (column names), you can read it this way (assuming that you want to read only second (`1`) and fourth (`3`) columns from the CSV file):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv', sep=',', usecols=[1,3],
                 header=None, names=['col1','col2'])
```

Comment: Thanks Max, it should be right, but I am quite new and I have still some problems. If i dont have a label, is it correct so:

Comment: data = pandas.read_csv(dataset, sep=',')
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
max2=df[1].nlargest(2)

Comment: @Giuseppe, you can do it this way: `df.iloc[:, 0].nlargest(2)`, where `0` - is your column number

Comment: Great, it works :) thanks a lot!