# How does np.partition() interpret the argument kth?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I am trying to figure out how `np.partition` function works.
For example, consider

```py
arr = np.array([5, 4, 1, 0, -1, -3, -4, 0])
```

If I call `np.partition(arr, kth=2)`, I get

```py
np.array([-4, -3, -1, 0, 1, 4, 5, 0])
```

I expect that, after partition, the array will split into elements *less than one*, *one*, and elements *greater than one*.
But the second zero is placed on the last array position, which isn't its right place after partition.

Comment: See documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html

Comment: Yes, i have. According to documentation, "The k-th value of the element will be in its final sorted position and all smaller elements will be moved before it and all equal or greater elements behind it.". Not a word about behaviour with non-unique arrays. I've figured out that partition on unique array works fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) says:

> Creates a copy of the array with its elements rearranged in such a way that
>   the value of the element in kth position is in the position it would be in
>   a sorted array. All elements smaller than the kth element are moved before
>   this element and all equal or greater are moved behind it. The ordering of
>   the elements in the two partitions is undefined.

In the example you give, you have selected 2th element of the sorted list (starting from zero), which is -1, and it seems to be in the right position if the array was sorted.

Comment: It may be 'clear', but it's easy to confuse `kth` position in the original array with `kth` position in the result.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Maybe that part could be emphasized more in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

> The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) talk of 'a sorted array'.

`np.partition` starts by sorting (see comment by @norok2) the elements in the array provided. In this case the original array is:

```
arr = [ 5,  4,  1,  0, -1, -3, -4,  0]
```

When sorted, we have:

```
arr_sorted = [-4 -3 -1  0  0  1  4  5]
```

Hence the call, `np.partition(arr, kth=2)`, will actually have the `kth` as the the element in position `2` of the `arr_sorted`, not `arr`. The element is correctly picked as `-1`.

Comment: except that it does not really sort the array. The elements before and after the k-th one can (and do) have arbitrary order.

Answer (score 2):

When I first read the official document of numpy.partition, I also interpreted its meaning in the same way as the OP did. I was confused when I read the examples given in the documents, and could not figure out where my understanding is wrong. I google it and got here.

Considering that the confusion is frequent, so the document should be revised. I suggest using the following:

Creates a copy of the array with its elements rearranged in such a way that: 
the k-th element of the new array is in the position it would be in a sorted array. All elements smaller than the k-th element are moved before this element and all greater are moved behind it. The ordering of the elements in the two partitions is undefined. If there are other elements that are equal to the k-th element, these elements may appear before or hehind the k-th element.