# How to filter a numpy array using a condition in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am using my numpy array `v` as follows to remove elements that are <=1 and then select the indexes of the top 3 elements in the numpy array.

```
 for ele in v.toarray()[0].tolist():
        if ele <= 1:
            useless_index = v.toarray()[0].tolist().index(ele)
            temp_list.append(useless_index)

 #take top 3 words from each document
 indexes =v.toarray()[0].argsort()[-3:]
 useful_list = list(set(indexes) - set(temp_list))
```

However, the current code I am using is very slow (as I have millions of numpy arrays) and take days to run. Is there any efficient way of doing the same thing in python?

Comment: Your indenting is a bit strange

Comment: What about `v[v > 1]`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
v = v[v > 1]
indices = np.argpartition(v, -3)[-3:]
values = v[indices]
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23734295/365102), `argpartition` runs in `O(n + k log k)` time. In your case, `n = 1e6`, `k=3`.