# Get indices of N maximum values in a numpy array without sorting them?

Tags: python, numpy

My question is very similar to this one: [How to get indices of N maximum values in a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-to-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array)

But I would like to get the indices in the same order I find them.

Let's take the example marked in that question as the correct solution:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1, 3, 2, 4, 5])
arr.argsort()[-3:][::-1]

array([4, 3, 1])
```

The result I'm looking for instead should be like:

```
array([1, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `arr.argsort()[-3:]`?

Comment: Hi Kasramvd, let's say exchange 4 and 3: arr = np.array([1, 4, 2, 3, 5]) , your solution would give array([3, 1, 4]) and not, again, array([1, 3, 4]) as I'm looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.argpartition()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
k = 3
np.argpartition(arr, len(arr) - k)[-k:]
```

Adjust `k` index to whatever you need.

NOTE: returned indices are not guaranteed to be in the "sorted order" - just that anything past index `k` is larger than the value at position `k` in the sorted array.

NOTE 2: If you do need the returned indices *to be sorted* themselves, then simply add a `numpy.sort()` to the above command:

```
np.sort(np.argpartition(arr, len(arr) - k)[-k:])
```

`numpy.argpartition()` provides significant performance gains over full `sort` especially for large `arr`. In the above example you do a full sort only over the selected indices (not all).

Answer (score 2):

It probably depends a bit on the sizes of `a` and `k` but often the fastest appears to be combining `partition` with `flatnonzero` or `where`:

```
>>> a = np.random.random(10000)
>>> k = 5
>>> 
>>> timeit("np.flatnonzero(a >= np.partition(a, len(a) - k)[len(a) - k])", globals=globals(), number=10000)
0.8328661819687113
>>> timeit("np.sort(np.argpartition(a, len(a) - k)[len(a) - k:])", globals=globals(), number=10000)
1.0577796879806556
>>> np.flatnonzero(a >= np.partition(a, len(a) - k)[len(a) - k])
array([2527, 4299, 5531, 6945, 7174])
>>> np.sort(np.argpartition(a, len(a) - k)[len(a) - k:])
array([2527, 4299, 5531, 6945, 7174])
```

Note 1: this highlights the significant performance cost of indirect indexing.

Note 2: as we only use the pivot element and discard the actual partition `percentile` should in theory be at least as fast but in practice it is way slower.