# How to get max (top) N values across entire numpy matrix

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matrix

I want to get the top N (maximal) args & values across an entire numpy matrix, as opposed to across a single dimension (rows / columns).

Example input (with `N=3`):

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.matrix([[9,8, 1, 2], [3, 7, 2, 5], [0, 3, 6, 2], [0, 2, 1, 5]])

print(mat)

[[9 8 1 2]
 [3 7 2 5]
 [0 3 6 2]
 [0 2 1 5]]
```

Desired output: `[9, 8, 7]`

Since max isn't transitive across a single dimension, going by rows or columns doesn't work.

```
# by rows, no 8
np.squeeze(np.asarray(mat.max(1).reshape(-1)))[:3]
array([9, 7, 6])

# by cols, no 7
np.squeeze(np.asarray(mat.max(0)))[:3]
array([9, 8, 6])
```

I have code that works, but looks really clunky to me.

```
# reshape into single vector
mat_as_vector = np.squeeze(np.asarray(mat.reshape(-1)))

# get top 3 arg positions
top3_args = mat_as_vector.argsort()[::-1][:3]

# subset the reshaped matrix
top3_vals = mat_as_vector[top3_args]

print(top3_vals)

array([9, 8, 7])
```

Would appreciate any shorter way / more efficient way / magic numpy function to do this!

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50533986 if you need _the indices_ of the top elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`numpy.partition()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) is significantly faster than performing full sort for this purpose:

```
np.partition(np.asarray(mat), mat.size - N, axis=None)[-N:]
```

assuming `N<=mat.size`.

If you need the final result also be sorted (besides being top `N`), then you need to sort previous result (but presumably you will be sorting a smaller array than the original one):

```
np.sort(np.partition(np.asarray(mat), mat.size - N, axis=None)[-N:])
```

If you need the result sorted from largest to lowest, post-pend `[::-1]` to the previous command:

```
np.sort(np.partition(np.asarray(mat), mat.size - N, axis=None)[-N:])[::-1]
```

Comment: @filippo All that means is that afterward there will be two regions in the array. Everything in one region will be greater than everything in the other, but the order inside those regions is not guaranteed by the function. Any seeming order it might have is accidental.

Comment: @HansMusgrave yep, that was actually my point, I assumed the desired outcome was the top sorted elements and `np.partition` was giving them as an accidental side effect, hence my doubt

Comment: @AGNGazer thanks for this great answer. i wonder -- is there a version of this that can give me the top N args as a stepping stone to the top N values?

Comment: @IdoS When using `argpartition()` with a flattened version of a multi-dimensional array, you may need to "unravel" the indices using `np.unravel_index(flat_indices, mat.shape)`.

Answer (score 3):

One way may be with `flatten` and `sorted` and slice top `n` values:

```
sorted(mat.flatten().tolist()[0], reverse=True)[:3]
```

Result:

```
[9, 8, 7]
```

Comment: In case anyone stumbles here from google, it's worth pointing out that in most instances numpy's vectorized operations will outperform other tricks from the standard library. This solution was 1.3-128x slower on my machine for various inputs than the `np.partition()` solution @AGN Gazer gave. If the solution doesn't need to be sorted then this solution is comparatively even much worse than that.

Comment: @HansMusgrave Thanks, the other solution is much faster.

Comment: That said, yours has the advantage of not using obscure function calls and being easy to include in a project when short on time. You might also like `sorted(np.asarray(mat).flatten())[-3:]` to avoid the list conversion and extra kwarg.

Answer (score -4):

The idea is from this answer: [How to get indices of N maximum values in a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-to-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array)

```
import numpy as np
import heapq

mat = np.matrix([[9,8, 1, 2], [3, 7, 2, 5], [0, 3, 6, 2], [0, 2, 1, 5]])
ind = heapq.nlargest(3, range(mat.size), mat.take)
print(mat.take(ind).tolist()[0])
```

**Output**

```
[9, 8, 7]
```

Comment: Why plagiarise an answer when you can flag as duplicate?

Comment: I don't think I plagiarized as I referenced the source.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Do you think it is entirely copy paste of original?

Comment: I understand frustration of the community about my answer. I honestly, did not know about the rules @chrisz referenced me to. I am glad he did as he offered constructive feedback why my answer is not in line with community guidelines.