# How to get index of columns from 2d numpy array containing max 3 values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have a array:

```
a = np.array([[22,11,44,33,66],
              [22,11,2,1,66],
              [1,11,44,22,4],
              [22,11,88,99,66]])
```

and as a output I want a array containing index of max 3 values as 2d array. For example for above array output would be:

```
array([[4,2,3],
       [4,0,1],
       [2,3,1],
       [3,2,4]])
```

Comment: Do the top values need to be sorted?

Comment: @Josh. It's pretty clear, unless it's me missing something: each output row contains the indices of the top 4 elements of the corresponding input row.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, indices of top 3 elements. Your solution below is not giving desired result

Comment: I updated answer with a fix and an explanation of why.

Comment: [How do I get indices of N maximum values in a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-do-i-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the top `k` elements of an array, [partition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) it. Since partitioning normally gives you the `k` lowest elements, use the reverse indices:

```
k = 3
top = np.argpartition(a, -k, axis=1)[:, -k:]
```

If you need to have the indices sorted in descending order, use [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) with the result:

```
rows = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None]
s = np.argsort(a[rows, top], axis=1)[:, ::-1]
top = top[rows, s]
```

`rows` is necessary to make sure that all the indices are selected properly when you do fancy indexing with `top` and `s`. The indices for each row have to be reversed (`[:, ::-1]`) to get ascending order.