# index of N highest elements from a list of numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I need a function that returns the index (row and column) of the N highest element from a matrix/list of numpy array.

Suppose that I have the following matrix:

```
a = [[4,2,3], 
     [5,0,3]]
```

I would like to get a list of the indexes (row,column) of the N highest elements. For example, if I want the index of the 4 highest element, the function should return

```
[(1,0), (0,0), (0,2), (1,2)]
```

I have tried implementing this as following, but it returns a list of (value, row number), which is not want I need

```
for i, sub_list in enumerate(a):
    max_list.append((max(sub_list), i))
```

Comment: I think you have an error in your output.  `(1, 2)` should be included instead of `(0, 1)`, since 3 > 2

Comment: Yes you are right. I have modified the question, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get indices of N maximum values in a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-do-i-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array) There are solutions for 2D arrays as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would flatten, `argsort`, and `unravel_index`

---

```
f = a.ravel().argsort()
[*zip(*np.unravel_index(f[-n:], a.shape))]
```

```
[(0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 0), (1, 0)]
```

---

As yatu points out, if you have a larger array, and a small-ish `n`, you can replace `argsort` with `np.argpartition(a.ravel(), -n)`.