# Python: Find most big Top-n values' index in List or numpy.ndarry

Tags: python, list, numpy

### For example:

```
a = [1,5,6,2,3]

result = most_find(a, 3)

reslut
[2,1,4]  # the index of 6, 5, 3 in a
```

I know how to implement this function with complex way....

### My question

Is there any built-in function in Python or numpy to deal with it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get indices of N maximum values in a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-do-i-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Yeah, thank you ! It's a easy way to work

Comment: If it is already a `numpy` array, then the linked `argsort` or `argpartition` should be fastest.  But if a list, then a list sort method is probably better.

Comment: @hpaulj, Okay, i get it ! Thanks. I was thinking this question, the direct way maybe more better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the index by value,

```py
def most_find(sequence, n):
    lst = sorted(range(len(sequence)), key=lambda x:sequence[x], reverse=True)
    return lst[:n]

a = [1, 5, 6, 2, 3]
result = most_find(a, 3)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in linked by Sushanth but you could also implement it like so: `sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: -a[i])[:3]`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any built-in function in Python or numpy to deal with it?

**As a matter of fact, there is! It's called [`numpy.argsort()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):**

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 5, 6, 2, 3]

print(np.array(a).argsort()[-3:][::-1]) # If you want to list the indexes of the 4 greatest numbers, change the -3 to -4, etc.
```

Output:

```
[2 1 4]
```