# Best and quickest way to get top N elements from a huge list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, multiprocessing

I am trying to workout the best solution for getting the top N elements with biggest number from a huge list with size of a few billions.
So far, I have got the idea of:

```
get the first N elements, sort them in descending order (list A). 
for N+1 to last element:
    min = the Nth element. 
    if the N+1 element > min then insert it into list A and sort it. 
        remove the last element
```

Practically, seems like it doesn't consume too much memory, and faster than just using list.sort of the entire huge list follow by getting top N elements

However, this sorting doesn't use the full capacity of the CPU with multi-cores. Is there any built-in function or any other approaches that would do the job with multi-processes? or able to fully utilizes the computing capabilities which would result much faster?

Comment: Python by itself is single threaded. You would have to use multiprocessing libraries to fully use multiple cores. If you provide a code sample, there may be more efficient ways to handle your problem.

Comment: ThreadPoolExecutor could be one possible solution. Although I would first just run this with PyPy if possible to see the difference in execution time.

Comment: You could also check out [`np.partition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html). Similar idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23734295/10166393). But is `list.sort` really not fast enough?

Comment: Feels like heapifying might be a better solution if N is small relative to the length of the list.

Comment: I haven't used NumPy package but running the under pypy3 win 32.

Comment: I am having developed a multiprocessing strategy, but not sure if I am doing smart enough. A number of threads acting as a consumer, taking the results then sort it and keep it with top N length and assign "min" as the Nth element. for any N+th smaller than min will be excluded, otherwise, update the list and min 
Once all results produced, take the top N elements of all those ordered result lists from threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use parallelize the work, you could use a python library such as Ray.

Using Ray, you could parallelize your search by partitioning the data into multiple sets and having each thread attempt to find the largest N numbers of each subset. Afterwards, you should have k lists of N 'large' numbers. From there, you can find the largest N numbers.

If you would like to learn more about Ray documentation, you can check out the documentation.

Documentation: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/