# Get coordinates in a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, max, indices

I have this `[116, 116]` array, and I would like to get the coordinates/indices of the 10 maximum values present in that array.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's create a test array *arr* as:

```
array([[  1,   2, 141,   4,   5,   6],
       [  7, 143,   9,  10,  11,  12],
       [ 13,  14,  15, 145,  17,  18],
       [ 19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24],
       [ 25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30]])
```

To find cordinates of e.g. **3** maximum values, run:

```
ind = np.divmod(np.flip(np.argsort(arr, axis=None)[-3:]), arr.shape[1])
```

The result is a 2-tuple with *row* and *column* coordinates:

```
(array([2, 1, 0], dtype=int64), array([3, 1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

To test it, you can print indicated elements:

```
arr[ind]
```

getting:

```
array([145, 143, 141])
```

Now replace *-3* with *-10* and you will get coordinates of **10**
max elements.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23734295/10940584) using [`np.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html).