# Find the index number of row and values of first 3 maximum values of 2D Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I have a 2D Numpy Array - arr2D = numpy.array([[11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16], [17, 15, 11],
[12, 14, 15]]).

- I want to find the first 3 largest values in above 2D array ==> 17, 16, 15
- I also want to get row index number of these values in an array ==> row index = 2,1,3

Can someone show me how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Also please provide more details (see comments in current answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort the flattened array with [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html?highlight=argsort#numpy.argsort) then divide the global indices by the number of columns to retrieve the row index:

```
>>> arg = (-x).flatten().argsort()
array([ 6,  5,  4,  7, 11,  3, 10,  2,  1,  9,  0,  8])

>>> arg[:3] // 3
array([2, 1, 1])
```

Which is row 2 (`17`), row 1 (`16`), and row 1 again (`15`).

Answer (score 0):

With arr2D.max(axis=1) you get the maximum value of every subarray.

And here: [How do I get indices of N maximum values in a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-do-i-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array) is the solution how to get the indices of the N largest elements.

Comment: Thanks for this, I went through answers and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23734295/7035448 is best speed wise and comparision of speed is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64724784/7035448 +1

Comment: OP doesn't seem to be looking for maximum *per* subarray, but rather the largest elements irrespective of subarrays.

Comment: If so, you're answer is the better match. But as you encountered in your answer, then the provided example [2, 1, 3] is wrong and should be [2, 1, 1]. I think OP has to clearify some things