# Put everything to zero in a np.array except n highest entries

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for the quickest way to do the following:

```
arr = np.array([2.,0.5,1.3,4.5,7.4])
```

I want to build a new array (or overwrite current) where I put to zero everything except the n highest entries.

```
[2.0,0,0,4.5,7.4]
```

Comment: Is it possible for `arr` to have duplicate entries?  If so, what output do you expect when, say `arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]` with `n = 2`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get indices of N maximum values in a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-do-i-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and indexing. This solution is in place:

```
arr = np.array([2.,0.5,1.3,4.5,7.4])

N = 3

# get the sorted order
idx = np.argsort(arr)[:-N]

# replace all but the N highest with 0
arr[idx]= 0
```

output: `array([2. , 0. , 0. , 4.5, 7.4])`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is the fastest or not but it gives the expected output

```
import numpy as np
array = np.array([2.,0.5,1.3,4.5,7.4])
l = len(array)
order = array.argsort()
ranks = order.argsort()

n = 3
array = [array[i] if ranks[i] >= l - n else 0 for i in range(len(ranks))]
print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's define the array and a value for N, so we keep the N highest elements.

```
N = 3
arr = np.array([2.,0.5,1.3,4.5,7.4])
```

Using argsort we can retrieve the order of elements from lower to highest. We just need to subtract from the size of the array to get from highest to lower.

```
order = arr.argsort()
order = arr.size - order
```

Then replace with zeros the smaller elements:

```
arr[order > N] = 0
```