# Get N Smallest values from numpy array with array size potentially less than N

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use `numpy.argpartition` to get the `n` smallest values from an array. However, I cannot guarantee that there will be at least `n` values in the array. If there are fewer than `n` values, I just need the entire array.

Currently I am handling this with checking the array size, but I feel like I'm missing a native numpy method that will avoid this branching check.

```py
if np.size(arr) < N: 
    return arr 
else:
    return arr[np.argpartition(arr, N)][:N]
```

Minimal reproducible example:

```py
import numpy as np

#Find the 4 smallest values in the array
#Arrays can be arbitrarily sized, as it's the result of finding all elements in a larger array
# that meet a threshold
small_arr = np.array([3,1,4])
large_arr = np.array([3,1,4,5,0,2])

#For large_arr, I can use np.argpartition just fine:
large_idx = np.argpartition(large_arr, 4)
#large_idx now contains array([4, 5, 1, 0, 2, 3])

#small_arr results in an indexing error doing the same thing:
small_idx = np.argpartition(small_arr, 4)
#ValueError: kth(=4) out of bounds (3)
```

I've looked through the numpy docs for truncation, max length, and other similar terms, but nothing came up that is what I need.

Comment: Could you clarify why you want to avoid the branching check? Are you looking for elegance, or do you have a measured performance concern?

Comment: Partially elegance, partially me trying to learn numpy better. If there isn't a built-in or native numpy solution, I'll just do the branching check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (depending on your situation) is just to cap the arg to `argparse` when the array is shorter with `min`:

```
return arr[np.argpartition(arr, min(N, arr.size - 1)][:N]
```

Slicing tolerates higher values than the array length, it's just `argpartition` that needs the `min()` check.

This is less efficient than your branch version, since it has to do the `argpartition` even when you just want the whole array, but it's more concise. So it depends what your priorities are - personally I'd probably keep the branch or use a ternary:

```
return arr if arr.size < N else arr[np.argpartition(arr, N)][:N]
```

Comment: That's what I was starting to guess. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't committing a numpy crime and missing some built in method.

Comment: @blackbrandt I could still be missing something, my own numpy knowledge is spotty. Doesn't look like it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
def nsmallest(array, n):
    return array[np.argsort(array)[:n]]
```

where `n` is the number of smallest values that you want.

Comment: It's worth noting that this has a [greater time complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6910641/11082165) than the OP's existing solution.

Comment: @Brian thanks for pointing that out, I already looked at using argsort and realized it sorts the entire array which would be a waste of time.