Maximum number of elements on list whose value sum up to at most K
I have an exercise asking:

Consider a vector T with n positive integers and an integer k. Present an algorithm that selects the maximum number of elements from T such that the sum of the selected elements is less than or equal to k.

What I did is:
 def findSumCount(L, k):
  L.sort()
  totalSum = L[0]
  count = 1
  for i in range(1, len(L), 1):
    if(totalSum + L[i] <= k):
      count = count + 1
      totalSum = totalSum + L[i]
    if(totalSum + L[i] > k): break

  return count

findSumCount([1, 2, 3, 4], 5)

I think this works when I sort the array on the entry (please give me a counter example if you think it does not work). But if I am not sorting before (i.e. iterate on the array without previously sorting it) I don't see a path forward. Any ideas?

"But if I am not sorting": you need to get the smallest elements, so if you don't want to sort that list, then call sorted? Not sure I understand the problem...

I was wondering how to solve the problem without sorting the entry array (so solving it on an unsorted array without sorting the entry prior the 'for'). Moreover as answered below is the best I can do (complexity-wise)

Your sorting approach is correct but your implementation doesn't handle cases where the smallest element in the list exceeds the threshold value (i.e cases where count would be 0). On the other hand, if you want to avoid sorting, you try do a more complex algorithm where you (binary) search for the largest element that can be selected where all smaller elements are also selected.

can you please elaborate on the binary search suggestion @wLui155? :) You mean I find the element that is at most K and then recursively build a list with all elements lower than this element found?

Not quite, you're searching for the largest element in the list where the sum of all elements smaller than or equal to it is below your k. No need to build a new list but the approach is a bit tricky. I'll see if I can whip up an answer explaining it.

I think this might actually be done in linear time using some modified version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect algorithm. Since this problem is similiar to finding m minimum elements whose sum is smaller than k. And introselect can find m minimum elements in O(n), where n is size of the input array. For more info, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-do-i-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array.

Taking as many elements having their sum below some k means you want to always choose elements with lowest value. So sorting the input array, and than taking elements in ascending order until k is exceeded is the best you can do. The complexity is than O(n logn + n) ~ O(n logn), where n is size of T. The cost you pay for sorting :).

If you don't want to mutate the input list by sorting it, you can always get a sorted list that is distinct from the input list. For that you just replace that initial statement with L = sorted(L). This L is now holding a list that is different from the initial one.
If k is relatively small in the sense that the number of elements to sum up is relatively small compared to the size of the list, then it may be more efficient to not sort the list, but build a heap from it instead. And then pull the minimum values from it until you have your count:
from heapq import heapify, heappop

def findSumCount(L, k):
    L = L[:]  # Optional. Use in case you don't want to mutate the original L
    heapify(L)  # Turn it into a heap
    totalSum = 0
    n = len(L)
    for count in range(n):
        totalSum += heappop(L)
        if totalSum > k:
            return count
    return n

The time complexity is O() for copying the list (optional) and also for heapifying the list. Each pop from the heap has a time complexity of O(log) where  is the size of the heap at that moment. So if we only have to pop  elements from the heap, the time complexity is O( + log).
In the worst case the time complexity will be O(log) in case all elements have to be popped from the list. In that case it has the same time complexity as the original code you presented, but with more overhead, so that in practice it will be slower.
Remark on your code
Your implementation has a few issues:

It would not return the correct answer if all elements in the list are greater than k, in which case the returned count should be 0.

It would evaluate the expression if(totalSum + L[i] > k) also when it had already executed the preceding if block, where L[i] was already added to totalSum: this is a bit strange. It would not lead to a wrong result, because the list is sorted, but still, it would be better to turn that second if into an else, or even better: invert the condition of the first if and return the count there. You'll at least save on the number of additions performed.

as the count really corresponds to the index of the currently iterated value from the sorted list, you could make that the loop variable. At the same time you can get the value with enumerate.


With these remarks taken into account it could be:
def findSumCount(L, k):
    L.sort()
    totalSum = 0
    for count, val in enumerate(L):
        totalSum += val
        if totalSum > k:
            return count
    return len(L)


As noted earlier it's entirely possible to solve this problem without sorting, or even much auxiliary space by incorporating a binary search. It relies on the below property for this problem (which has already been identified):
It is optimal to pick smaller elements into the array before larger ones since the smaller ones contribute less to the overall sum, and we'd like to pick as many elements as possible while keeping the sum of the selected elements below k.
Twisting this idea, we can maximize the number of elements selected by instead finding the largest element limit where we pick all elements smaller than or equal to limit. One way of finding limit would be to test each value in the array, but we can actually do better by picking only certain candidates for limit using a binary search, as we simply want to maximize limit and can immediately discard candidates that are too small/too large quickly.
The full code is below, with findSumCountBsearch being an implementation of this idea; it calls helper to evaluate if the candidate works as a proposed limit. There's also an edge case where all elements smaller than the limit can be safely included, but only a subset of all the instances of limit can actually be selected, which can be handled with some math.
import random
from math import ceil

BAD, OK, DONE = 0, 1, 2
def findSumCountBsearch(L, k):
    """
    Determine the largest number of elements in L that can be selected
    s.t the sum of the selected elements is smaller than or equal to k
    
    Does so via binary search on the biggest element we can pick; works
    bc if we want to include value x into the sum, we have to allow
    all values smaller than x into it anyways
    """
    lo, hi = min(L), max(L) # binary searching on min/max; array doesn't need to be sorted!
    res_limit, res_cnt = 0, 0
    while lo < hi:
        mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
        status, cnt = helper(L, k, mid)
        if status == BAD: # search left
            hi = mid
        else:
            res_cnt = cnt
            res_limit = mid
            if status == DONE:
                return res_cnt
            
            lo = mid + 1
            
    if lo <= res_limit: # can't do any better
        return res_cnt
        
    status, cnt = helper(L, k, lo)
    if status != BAD:
        res_cnt = cnt
        
    return res_cnt

def helper(L, k, limit):
    """
    Can we pick all elements in L that are smaller than limit
    where the sum is smaller than or equal to k?
    
    Also need to handle the case where we pick the largest number <=
    limit but specifically, a few of them
    """
    res, curr_sum, curr_max, max_cnt = 0, 0, None, 0
    for x in L:
        if x <= limit:
            res += 1
            curr_sum += x
            if curr_max is None or x > curr_max:
                curr_max = x
                max_cnt = 1
            elif x == curr_max:
                max_cnt += 1
            
    if curr_sum <= k:
        return (1, res)
        
    # curr_sum above k so see if we can remove some of the largest elements
    max_remove = max_cnt * curr_max
    if curr_sum - max_remove > k: # still too big
        return (0, -1)
        
    # want p, the number of times we need to remove the largest element,
    # to satisfy curr_sum - p * curr_max <= k and p is as small as possible
    # => (curr_sum - k) / (curr_max) <= p
    p = ceil((curr_sum - k) / curr_max)
    return (DONE, res - p)
    
def findSumCount(L, k):
    """
    Your solution but modified a little
    """
    L = sorted(L) # avoid mutation
    if L[0] > k: # handle edge case
      return 0
      
    totalSum = L[0]
    count = 1
    for i in range(1, len(L), 1):
        if(totalSum + L[i] <= k):
            count = count + 1
            totalSum = totalSum + L[i]
        if(totalSum + L[i] > k): break
    
    return count
  
def generate_test():
    L = [random.randint(-10, 1000) for _ in range(random.randint(5, 100))]
    k = random.randint(min(L), max(L) * random.randint(1, len(L) // 2))
    return (L, k)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for L, k in [
        ([1,2,3,4], 5),
        ([4,2,1,3], 5), # some permutation of the above
    ]:
        print(f"{L =}, {k =}, result: {findSumCountBsearch(L, k) = }")
        assert findSumCountBsearch(L, k) == findSumCount(L, k), f"Mismatch for {(L, k)}"
    
    for L, k in [generate_test() for _ in range(1000)]: # some bigger tests to catch more cases
        act, exp = findSumCountBsearch(L, k), findSumCount(L, k)
        assert act == exp, f"Mismatch for {(L, k)}; {act} vs {exp}"


This still looks like O(n log n) because you need log n for the binary search outer loop and for each iteration of the outer loop you iterate the whole length of the array in helper. Seems an interesting idea nevertheless.

I'd say it's more along the lines of O(n log m) where m is equal to the difference between the extremes of the input array, but you're right that the entire array is iterated on each helper call. One of the pros is that it doesn't require extra space for a sort, but a pretty big con is that it was kind of a pain to actually implement, being much more clunky than the sorting approach.

I dont think this should work, but I havent tried it and I might just not understand. But I just dont get, what is binary search good for in unsorted array? Did you try it for bigger input arrays? If it really chooses m minimum elements whose sum is below k?

@TomasTillmann it's not a binary search through the array. It's a binary search for the answer, by iteratively doing a "binary chop" of hi and lo. Check the code carefully. The original author might be able to explain it better.

@Tomas Tillmann Paragraphs 2 and 3 explain how a property of the original problem allows for reformulating to a new problem, whose solution is the same as that of the original. The new problem involves finding the largest limit <= max(L) where sum(L[i] <= limit) <= k. There are a few ways to find limit including exhaustively checking min(L), min(L) + 1, ..., max(L), sorting L then taking a running sum (which is essentially what OP's solution does), and binary searching [min(L), max(L)]. Note that testing each candidate limit using binary search doesn't require L to be sorted.
