# How to parse a python list for largest N values?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have attached data at the bottom of this post. I have output from another program that I would like to parse in python in a reasonable way.

The output will always be in the same form, and what I would like to do is find out which "tag" has the largest value. I've labeled a truncated version of the data below (and labeled the top of the column)

```
0        1               2                3            4        5            6          7              8         
AlII     1.6272514892aa  0.0000042282     5.85216aa    0.68792  10.741103    0.074253   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6273145922ab  0.0000129136     0.50000ab    1.41279  10.483775    0.516978   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6272514892AA  0.0000000000     5.85217AA    0.00000  11.510502    3.9484     0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
```

So what I'd like to do is parse this file in a number of ways. From the abbreviated one above I'd like to return the following:

- Largest (column 2): AlII ab: 0.0000129136
- Largest (column 4): AlII ab: 1.41279
- Largest (column 6): MgII AA: 3.9484

And I'd actually like to do the top N largest values, but for the example I'll just do the largest. I'm getting bogged down by creating new lists, and finding the indexes of these new lists. Is there some straightforward way of doing this kind of parsing? Or is it going to be a messy process?

**EDIT**

I've been asked to give some code showing what I've tried.

```
import numpy as np
analyseList = []
with open('output.ascii', 'r') as f18:
  for line in f18.read().splitlines():
    analyseList.append(line.split())

for column in [2, 4, 6]:
  winner = analyseList[np.argmax(np.column_stack(np.array(analyseList))[column])]
  print winner[0], winner[1][-2:], winner[column]
```

Of course this only returns the largest value (and I'd like to be able to do the N largest). Also, it just looks like I'm doing it in the least straightforward way possible.

To get the index values of the top N largest values, I can do (using the suggestion from ):

```
[list(analyse_array[2]).index(x) for x in heapq.nlargest(5, analyse_array[2])]
```

Am I doing some super-convoluted stuff?

```
AlII     1.6272514892aa  0.0000042282     5.85216aa    0.68792  10.741103    0.074253   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6273145922ab  0.0000129136     0.50000ab    1.41279  10.483775    0.516978   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6273482473ac  0.0000118688     2.01059ac    3.95256  10.714536    0.646238   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6273975034ad  0.0000379662     3.78319ad    5.42225  11.118654    0.683413   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6274362338ae  0.0000137972     2.17566ae    2.17134  11.105118    1.025574   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6274729985af  0.0000071899     2.59672af    1.62035  11.686851    0.218038   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6275047836ag  0.0000059328     0.56225ag    0.73486  10.908730    0.729322   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6275333529ah  0.0000063501     2.46788ah    1.66430  11.280185    0.381467   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6275811952ai  0.0000273404     4.39490ai    3.90964  11.154901    0.430842   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6276822766ak  0.0000153451     3.86075ak    1.01659  11.687808    0.302170   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6277080822al  0.0000041420     2.77773al    0.74546  11.515588    0.594305   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6277357442am  0.0000180202     3.03343am    2.97410  11.311138    0.474284   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6277884119an  0.0000100139     3.05039an    1.49107  11.218137    0.271466   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6278358107cd  0.0000488929     3.80549cd    6.28261  11.103154    1.305702   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6278657638ao  0.0000095109     4.23025ao    1.26277  11.681221    0.419769   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6279139560bq  0.0000074039     2.68827bq    1.66201  11.457767    0.630426   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6280021360cb  0.0000058565     1.55711cb    1.67734  11.188839    0.706256   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6280408039cc  0.0000168737     3.88995cc    2.74610  11.520547    0.303991   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6279628448ar  0.0000059612     4.02312ar    2.18053  11.975320    0.228508   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6280940230as  0.0000033920     0.61137as    0.37590  10.717869    0.253534   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6281299959at  0.0000035012     0.90119at    0.58387  10.833329    0.072094   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6281673440au  0.0000048884     0.50000au    0.84155  10.339533    0.191522   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlII     1.6282125019av  0.0000068319     7.51956av    1.17482  11.097728    0.069789   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6272514892AA  0.0000000000     5.85217AA    0.00000  11.510502    0.039484   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6273145922AB  0.0000000000     0.50000AB    0.00000  11.176308    0.522596   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6273482473AC  0.0000000000     2.01060AC    0.00000  11.450444    0.591724   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6273975034AD  0.0000000000     3.78320AD    0.00000  11.803555    0.736543   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6274362338AE  0.0000000000     2.17568AE    0.00000  11.967321    0.821801   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6274729985AF  0.0000000000     2.59673AF    0.00000  12.458430    0.235348   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6275047836AG  0.0000000000     0.56231AG    0.00000  11.941490    0.332862   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6275333529AH  0.0000000000     2.46790AH    0.00000  12.037696    0.343867   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6275811952AI  0.0000000000     4.39491AI    0.00000  11.840805    0.451418   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6276822766AK  0.0000000000     3.86076AK    0.00000  12.497054    0.314167   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6277080822AL  0.0000000000     2.77775AL    0.00000  12.391999    0.522446   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6277357442AM  0.0000000000     3.03344AM    0.00000  12.112177    0.481882   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6277884119AN  0.0000000000     3.05040AN    0.00000  12.013911    0.321297   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6278358107CD  0.0000000000     3.80550CD    0.00000  12.061481    1.335432   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6278657638AO  0.0000000000     4.23025AO    0.00000  12.520703    0.551397   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6279139560BQ  0.0000000000     2.68828BQ    0.00000  12.419351    0.538659   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6280021360CB  0.0000000000     1.55713CB    0.00000  11.993443    0.736608   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6280408039CC  0.0000000000     3.88996CC    0.00000  12.272450    0.312588   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6279628448AR  0.0000000000     4.02313AR    0.00000  12.836074    0.241956   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6280940230AS  0.0000000000     0.61143AS    0.00000  11.738664    0.119798   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6281299959AT  0.0000000000     0.90123AT    0.00000  11.522748    0.084764   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6281673440AU  0.0000000000     0.50000AU    0.00000  11.179284    0.155217   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6282125019AV  0.0000000000     7.51956AV    0.00000  11.963228    0.066024   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgII     1.6282950406aw  0.0000162434     0.50000aw   18.49632  10.153640    0.769463   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 1.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6276822766AK  0.0000000000     3.86071AK    0.00000  11.593048    0.330634   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6277080822AL  0.0000000000     2.77768AL    0.00000  11.784789    0.214666   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6277884119AN  0.0000000000     3.05033AN    0.00000  11.072150    0.276522   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6278358107CD  0.0000000000     3.80545CD    0.00000  11.147939    1.295144   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6278657638AO  0.0000000000     4.23021AO    0.00000  11.660933    0.468554   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6279139560BQ  0.0000000000     2.68821BQ    0.00000  11.427745    0.662669   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6280021360CB  0.0000000000     1.55700CB    0.00000  10.341299    3.837088   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6280408039CC  0.0000000000     3.88991CC    0.00000  11.289446    0.290091   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6279628448AR  0.0000000000     4.02308AR    0.00000  11.989071    0.212467   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6280940230AS  0.0000000000     0.61111AS    0.00000   9.766184    1.484659   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6281299959AT  0.0000000000     0.90101AT    0.00000  10.590012    0.186610   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6281673440AU  0.0000000000     0.50000AU    0.00000  10.186119    0.472566   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
FeII     1.6282125019AV  0.0000000000     7.51954AV    0.00000  11.190375    0.088965   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6272514892AA  0.0000000000     5.85216AA    0.00000  10.321950    0.459616   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6273145922AB  0.0000000000     0.50000AB    0.00000  10.097437    0.853198   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6273482473AC  0.0000000000     2.01059AC    0.00000  10.102194    1.947396   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6273975034AD  0.0000000000     3.78319AD    0.00000  11.105979    0.686387   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6274362338AE  0.0000000000     2.17566AE    0.00000  11.175948    0.814687   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6274729985AF  0.0000000000     2.59672AF    0.00000  11.548086    0.275875   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6275047836AG  0.0000000000     0.56225AG    0.00000  11.108123    0.386412   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6275333529AH  0.0000000000     2.46788AH    0.00000  11.292689    0.333124   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6275811952AI  0.0000000000     4.39490AI    0.00000  11.057781    0.453329   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6276822766AK  0.0000000000     3.86075AK    0.00000  11.265981    0.325767   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6277080822AL  0.0000000000     2.77773AL    0.00000  11.117329    0.630136   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6277357442AM  0.0000000000     3.03343AM    0.00000  10.921103    0.639479   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6277884119AN  0.0000000000     3.05039AN    0.00000  11.191087    0.159695   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6278657638AO  0.0000000000     4.23025AO    0.00000  11.504725    0.162766   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6279139560BQ  0.0000000000     2.68827BQ    0.00000  11.185086    0.780060   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6280021360CB  0.0000000000     1.55711CB    0.00000  10.744751    1.475204   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6280408039CC  0.0000000000     3.88995CC    0.00000  11.471091    0.278311   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6279628448AR  0.0000000000     4.02312AR    0.00000  11.854733    0.209241   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6280940230AS  0.0000000000     0.61137AS    0.00000  10.205223    0.810373   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6281299959AT  0.0000000000     0.90119AT    0.00000  10.823697    0.155524   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6281673440AU  0.0000000000     0.50000AU    0.00000  10.582535    0.258096   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
AlIII    1.6282125019AV  0.0000000000     7.51956AV    0.00000  10.874901    0.182424   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6272514892AA  0.0000000000     5.85217AA    0.00000   9.963618    0.199973   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6273975034AD  0.0000000000     3.78320AD    0.00000  10.008887    0.626172   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6274362338AE  0.0000000000     2.17568AE    0.00000  10.029316    0.772678   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6274729985AF  0.0000000000     2.59673AF    0.00000  10.171716    0.390966   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6275047836AG  0.0000000000     0.56231AG    0.00000   9.914891    0.378870   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6275333529AH  0.0000000000     2.46790AH    0.00000  10.075757    0.224531   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6276822766AK  0.0000000000     3.86076AK    0.00000  10.525614    0.306759   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6277080822AL  0.0000000000     2.77775AL    0.00000  10.460383    0.403447   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6277357442AM  0.0000000000     3.03344AM    0.00000   9.791121    0.536106   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6278657638AO  0.0000000000     4.23025AO    0.00000  10.746795    0.126158   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6279139560BQ  0.0000000000     2.68828BQ    0.00000  10.134445    0.921959   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6280021360CB  0.0000000000     1.55713CB    0.00000   9.964342    0.676227   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6280408039CC  0.0000000000     3.88996CC    0.00000  10.126811    0.368050   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6279628448AR  0.0000000000     4.02313AR    0.00000  10.750671    0.228670   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6280940230AS  0.0000000000     0.61143AS    0.00000   9.405961    0.588696   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6281299959AT  0.0000000000     0.90123AT    0.00000   9.292788    0.728340   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
MgI      1.6281673440AU  0.0000000000     0.50000AU    0.00000   9.807055    0.210571   0.0000E+00QA  0.0000E+00  0 [   0.000   0.000 0.000E+00 0.000E+00
```

Comment: example code always helps us help you better. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've added some of my code to the prompt.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807047/pythonnumpy-efficient-way-to-take-the-min-max-n-values-and-indices-from-a-matr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a list-of-lists to start with, you could do something using just the stdlib(untested and most certainly will need tweaking) such as:

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter

# get a two tuple of (idx, row)
list_with_index = enumerate(your_list)

# Get the top 10 from column '1' and return a list of those
# which will be (row_index, original_row)
largest = heapq.nlargest(10, list_with_index, key=itemgetter(1, 1))

# Get the top 5 index values
largest_indices = [el[0] for el in largest]
# or map(itemgetter(0), largest) if you prefer...
```

Based on your example code (again untested):

```
for colno in (2, 4, 6):
    largest = map(itemgetter(0), heapq.nlargest(10, enumerate(analyseList), key=itemgetter(1, colno)))
    print '{} largest: {}'.format(colno, ', '.join(largest))
```

On a side note you could also consider looking at `.argsort` on a numpy array.

Comment: so I can do this: [list(analyse_array[2]).index(x) for x in heapq.nlargest(5, analyse_array[2])]
which will return the top 5 index values from column 2 of the output. Is this along the lines of what you're suggesting?

Comment: @JBWhitmore updated to show how to retrieve indices... You've already got the index as part of the result - you don't need to re-search to find it... Read through my comments...

Answer (score 1):

Have you access to the NumPy package? You could load your whole 2D list in a single `ndarray` (if you want, with the first string column too). Then you could use the `argmax` method of your array to find the position of the maximum along each column using `argmax(axis=0)` or each line `argmax(axis=1)`...

Assuming that you construct your array column by column, you could do:

```
analyse_array = np.column_stack(analyse_list)
col_max = analyse_array.argmax(axis=0)
```

That gives you an array giving the position of the maximum for each column, as the index of the row. If you want the results only for columns 2, 4, 6, just use fancy indexing:

```
col_max[[2,4,6]]
```

That way, you can retrieve the corresponding rows as

```
analyse_array[col_max[[2,4,6]]]
```

Comment: I've added some code showing what I've tried... any suggestions on what to do from here?