# How to find two largest eigenvector in python?

Tags: python

I can find eigenvectors of a matrix in Python as follows:

```
from numpy import linalg as LA
w, v = LA.eig(np.diag((1, 2, 3)))
```

But how to find the largest two eigenvectors for a larger matrix of size 100*200?

Comment: A matrix of size `100 x 200` won't have eigenvectors. Did you mean singular values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to take the minimum/maximum n values and indices from a matrix using NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807047/efficient-way-to-take-the-minimum-maximum-n-values-and-indices-from-a-matrix-usi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvalue decomposition is not defined for a non-square matrix.  The closest operation is [single value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).  SVD and EIG for a non-square matrix are related in that the single values are the square root of the eigenvalues of the transpose of the matrix times itself.

```
B = A' * A
SVD(A) * SVD(A) ~= EIG(B)
```

So one potential answer to your question is:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
B = np.matmul(np.transpose(A), A)
u,s,v = np.linalg.svd(A)
V, D = np.linalg.eig(B)
print(f'Compare s*s to V {s*s - V}')
```

While `s` is not directly the eigenvalues of `A` it is somewhat related.